# alphanumeric sorting in java script

Tags: javascript, sorting

i am having the field which has data in this way .
         A_0121-X-1
  A_0121-X-10
  A_0121-X-11
   A_0121-X-2
   A_0121-X-3 
         A_0121-Z-1
         A_0121-Z-11
         A_0121-Z-12 
         A_0121-Z-13
         A_0121-Z-2 
         A_0121-Z-3
S0 How to sort numerically like this

A_0121-X-1
   A_0121-X-2
   A_0121-X-3
         A_0121-X-10
         A_0121-X-11 
         A_0121-Z-1
         A_0121-Z-2 
         A_0121-Z-3
         A_0121-Z-11
         A_0121-Z-12 
         A_0121-Z-13

Thanks in advance

Comment: @joseph , why do you want to do these type of stuff using...javascript , they are lot of rich ui controls to do all these type of stuff...

Comment: can u suggest some existing ui controls wre i can find these type of stuff

Answer (score 2):

i think you mean to natural sort in js

look on Brian Huisman solution

https://web.archive.org/web/20130929122019/http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1671288