# Jquery sort table data with numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesort

Jquery sort table data with numbers

I have sorted this table in ascending order but I want it in order of a1,a2,a3,a11.

Can anyone help, please?

```js
function sortTable(table, order) {
        var asc   = order === 'asc',
            tbody = table.find('tbody');
        tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
            if (asc) {
                return jQuery('td:first', a).text().localeCompare(jQuery('td:first', b).text());
        } else {
            return jQuery('td:first', b).text().localeCompare(jQuery('td:first', a).text());
        }
        }).appendTo(tbody);
        }

        sortTable($('#mytable'),'asc');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table name="mytable" id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>a 11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a 1</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Remember that the `.sort()` function sorts lexicographically, meaning that `11` will always come after `1` but before `2`, for example. If you want to look for **natural sort**, you can try third-party plugins, such as: [natsort](https://github.com/bubkoo/natsort). There are also other solutions already available on StackOverflow, just search for **natural sort**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Array of numeric & alphabetical elements (Natural Sort)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373018/sort-array-of-numeric-alphabetical-elements-natural-sort)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set options parameter as `{numeric: true }`

```js
var sorted = $('#mytable tbody tr').sort(function(a, b) {
  var a = $(a).find('td:first').text(), b = $(b).find('td:first').text();
  return a.localeCompare(b, false, {numeric: true})
})

$('#mytable tbody').html(sorted)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table name="mytable" id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>a 11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a 1</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because comparison is done from left to right, you can try to pad numbers with zeros like a 01, a 02, a 03, a 11

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer. But i want it like 1,2,3 only. can not add 0.

Answer (score 0):

@Nenad nailed it: 'kn' does not seem to work, use option `numeric` in .localeCompare() like:

```
.localeCompare(jQuery('td:first', b).text(),'en',{numeric:true});
```

This will take care of the numbering problem. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare