# array.sort() does not work in IE 11 with compareFunction

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sorting, internet-explorer-11, plunker

I'm sorting an array following [JavaScript Array sort() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp). When I use a `compareFunction` parameter, Internet Explorer 11 is not sorting properly.

I have a team array with players. These players have names:

```
var team = [
  {name:"Waldo"}, 
  {name:"Sarah"}
  ];
```

But I want to display them at the stadium video board sort by alphabetical order. So I have a list to append them when the DOM is ready:

MyHtml

```
<h2>My Team after sorting</h2>
      <button onclick='sortAndDisplay()'>Click here to sort by Name</button>
      <ul id="myTeamAfter">

      </ul>
```

My Javascript code

```
function sortAndDisplay(){
  $("#myTeamAfter").empty();
  team.sort(function(a, b){return a.name > b.name;});
  for(var i=0; i < team.length; i++){
    $("#myTeamAfter").append( "<li>" + team[i].name + "</li>" );
  }
}
```

Problem is that some Clubs use Internet Explorer 11 at their stadiums, and sort() function when I use my own `compareFunction` is not working properly on IE11, so Waldo is displayed first than Sarah and the fans are confused.

I've created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TNsa5N?p=preview) where you can reproduce it:

- Firefox 33.1                - Working!! :)
- Chrome 39.0.2171.65         - Working!! :)
- Internet Explorer 11.0.9600 - Not Working :(

Any idea to resolve the sort() for every browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your comparer looks incorrect:

```
function(a, b){return a.name > b.name;}
```

This returns `true` or `false`, while it should return `-1`, `0` or `1` depending on the ordering.

See [How to sort strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165/how-do-you-do-string-comparison-in-javascript) (specifically [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)).

So code should be:

```
function sortAndDisplay() {
  $("#myTeamAfter").empty();
  team.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
    if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
  for (let i = 0; i < team.length; i++) {
    $("#myTeamAfter").append("<li>" + team[i].name + "</li>");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx @Kos! I've edited your answer with a working code.

Comment: In fact IE seems to assimilates 0 to 1, because when I return 0 or 1 the sort is not effective. It only works if I return 1 or -1.