# How to sort key value pairs in javascript

Tags: typescript

I have an object:

```
[name: string]: Person;
```

I would like to sort it by key, which is `Person's` name. Is it possible to do so or this kind of map is unsortable or I should replace it with collection of different type, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: When you say "map", do you mean [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to sort a ES6 map object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158902/is-it-possible-to-sort-a-es6-map-object)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts No i don't, I mean whatever is in the code in my question because some people at my work don't use proper collections and types but stuff like you see above instead.

Comment: even if you have a sorted map, how do you use it with that information?

Comment: @NinaScholz I imagine affecting the iteration order of a `for..in` loop would be helpful in executing linear searches with an expected outcome.

Comment: @NinaScholz This map is part of redux state which part will be iterated to generate controls in the form in the specified order. I need it sorted.

Comment: Same as in JavaScript: you can't. You can however get the keys using `Object.keys(obj)` and sort it and use the properties.

Answer (score 2):

An object is *technically* sortable, though doing so tends to raise the question of why you are using one in the first place.

However, to address your concern with as little hassle as possible, here's one way to affect the insertion order of an object's keys:

```js
function sortMap(map, compare) {
  return Object
    .entries(map)
    .sort(compare)
    .reduce((map, [key, value]) => Object.assign(map, {
      [key]: value
    }), {})
}

console.log(sortMap({
  "Joe": {},
  "Bob": {},
  "Alice": {},
  "Kevin": {},
  "Sarah": {}
}, ([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b)))
```

References:

- [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order/23202095#23202095)
- [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [`Array#sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

As is stated in the linked answer, relying on the insertion order of an object does not guarantee the iteration order, since it is not in the specification, but it is currently a *de-facto* standard in many implementations, and it does not appear that this behavior will change in the future.

For a formal guarantee of iteration order by the specification, use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), as recommended in comments.

As an addendum, here's how to sort a map's iteration order, if you should choose to use them instead:

```js
function sortMap(map, compare) {
  return new Map(
    Array
      .from(map)
      .sort(compare)
  )
}

let people = new Map([
  ['Joe', {}],
  ['Bob', {}],
  ['Alice', {}],
  ['Kevin', {}],
  ['Sarah', {}]
])

let sorted = sortMap(
  people,
  ([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b)
)

console.log(Array.from(sorted))
```