# Javascript Map.set at position

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there any way that I can insert an new element into a Map before of or after an existing key?
as for Array would be: `arr.splice(<POSITION>, 0, <NEW ELEMENT>);`

Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask why? This sounds like a strange request.

Comment: you can traverse and do it, have you tried this or this is your question?

Comment: No is the short answer, maps don't necessarily maintain position.

Comment: Are you asking about [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)?

Comment: Asking  about Map. Looks like the only way is .set() a new element and then sort

Comment: You could re-create the map on every insertion and just insert the elements in the order you want. Depending on whether insertion or iteration happens more often, that could be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### general theory

[A Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) does –unlike an array– not have the semantics of “order”.

It's designed to be most efficient for storing&retrieving values for specific keys. (In fact, it's internal implementation does some structuring/ordering specifically optimized for that, “[b-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)” being the keyword here.

#### javascript implementation

Despite all that, [mozilla docs say:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

> A Map object iterates its elements in insertion order — a for...of loop returns an array of [key, value] for each iteration.

**update**: The official ECMA-262 standard [confirms this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map.prototype.foreach).

*personally, I am guessing, implementors will keep a separate index for order-of-entry **and** a b-tree for most efficient singular access.*

Based on this, what you would have to do is essentially, treating the map like an immutable object, and creating a new one from it:

1. iterate over the prior map
2. add each element to a new map. – when the right time comes, insert *your* element. – Keep iterating for the rest of it
3. assign your new element to the name of the old one.

---

I don't now your specific use case, but perhaps your problems could also be solved by [sort Iteration to specific criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31159284/444255) right when iterating over it.

Comment: This is wrong, the `Map` that you linked actually *does* have an order. It always iterates the elements in insertion order.

Comment: @Frank Nocke I see developer.mozilla.org says "A Map object iterates its elements in insertion order", so I guess the only way, as you said is to sort the map

Comment: Thank you both <3, I adjusted my answer!

Comment: This is still wrong: "A Map does –unlike an array– not have the semantics of 'order'." While MDN is great for web developers, it is not an authoritative resource. But most articles on MDN link to the actual one in the "Specifications" section. For example, the [authoritative specification of `Map`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-map-objects). In fact, you can also read some implementation details.

Comment: @str The spec does not have any implementation details, it only states *behavioural* details. But yeah, maps do ("somehow") keep insertion order and the algorithm described in the answer is the only way to "insert in the middle".

Comment: @Bergi I was relating to "Map object must be implemented using either hash tables or other mechanisms that, on average, provide access times that are sublinear on the number of elements in the collection." Yes that is not very specific, but not just behavioural either.

Comment: Update: found it in [the official spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map.prototype.foreach) I think…