# A way to Swap the position of Map elements

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have json objects stored in a javascript Map. These items are ordered in according to how they were added to the Map.

```
var rows =  new Map();

rows.set(1, A);
rows.set(3, B);
rows.set(4, C);
rows.set(7, D);
// A, B, C, D
```

Now I would like to move an object up or down one position, is there a way to do this.

```
rows.swap(1, 3);
// B, A, C, D
```

Comment: You should not use a `Map` if you want to set a specific order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to sort a ES6 map object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31158902/1048572)

Comment: I don't want to Sort the items. I only want to change the order of max 2 items

Comment: It's the same issue - maps don't support this kind of operation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to sort a ES6 map object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158902/is-it-possible-to-sort-a-es6-map-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Disclaimer**
>
> [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)
>
> Oherwise an array is the best data structure for reordering items.

You need to delete all key/value pairs and assign new ordered items to `this`.

```js
Map.prototype.swap = function (a, b) {
    var all = [...this],
        indexA = all.findIndex(([v]) => v === a),
        indexB = all.findIndex(([v]) => v === b);
    
    [all[indexA], all[indexB]] = [all[indexB], all[indexA]];
    this.forEach((_, k, m) => m.delete(k));
    all.forEach(([k, v]) => this.set(k, v));
}

var rows =  new Map;

rows.set(1, 'A');
rows.set(3, 'B');
rows.set(4, 'C');
rows.set(7, 'D');

rows.swap(1, 3);

console.log([...rows]);
```

Comment: I'm missing the advice that this is a bad idea.

Comment: it is a bad idea.