# How to sort map of JSONObject

Tags: java, android

I have a map of `JSONObject` and `Integer`. I want to sort it in an incremental order using its values, here is what I've done so far:

```
Map<JSONObject, Integer> unsortedMap = new HashMap<>();

unsortedMap.put(jsonObject2.getJSONObject(key),key1);
```

Comment: why HashMap when there's a SortedMap?

Comment: This question was answered well here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158902/is-it-possible-to-sort-a-es6-map-object/31159284

Comment: @SeanSchoeman it is in javascript can you help me do it in java / android

Comment: I recommend you to use a `TreeMap` with a custom comparator. There is already a question on this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TreeMap sort by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864840/treemap-sort-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use an Object as a key in a hashmap?  It's normal practice to use immutable values for keys.  The slightest change in any of the elements of the JSONObject will change the hash value and you will be unable to get your info back out of the map.

What is the integer value of your map?

Only a suggestion but you may want to check out the Java API for collection and see if there is anything that better suits your needs. [Java Collection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)

In the past I have wanted a sorted list with no duplicates.  I had to first write to a TreeMap and then write to a SortedSet to get the result I wanted.  Not code efficient, but I couldn't achieve what I wanted any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best option but could help:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> SortByKey(Map<String, Integer> map) 
    { 
        ArrayList<String> sortedKeys = 
                    new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet()); 

        Collections.sort(sortedKeys);  

        Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (String x : sortedKeys)  
            sortedMap.put(map.get(x), Integer.parseInt(x));

        return sortedMap;
    }
```