# How to sort a specific value in a map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, hashmap

I would like to sort my map by the value "time". But I do not know how to do. I googled a lot but I can't make it work.

Maybe someone could help me please.

My Map looks like this:

```
this.map.set(userData.data()['uid'], { data: userData.data(), lastChat: {message: messages[0].msg, time: messages[0].time}});

uid: {
      data: sampleData,
      lastChat: {
                 message: "A sample text"
                 time: 1640063014931
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maps iterate in the order the items are added, to sort a map you must generate a new map adding the items in the sorted order. Further details on sorting a Map can be found at [Is it possible to sort a ES6 map object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158902/is-it-possible-to-sort-a-es6-map-object).

To generate a new sorted Map you can:

1. Place the entries from the map into an array e.g. `[...map]`. Each entry will be added as an array where [0] is the key and [1] is the value.
2. Sort the array on the time property from the value `.sort((a, b) => a[1].lastChat.time - b[1].lastChat.time)`.
3. Generate a new Map with the result

Below is an example based on the property mentioned in the question.

```js
var map = new Map();
map.set('0001', {lastChat: {message: 'test', time: 1640063014931}});
map.set('0002', {lastChat: {message: 'test', time: 1640063014930}});

var sortedMap = new Map([...map].sort((a, b) => a[1].lastChat.time - b[1].lastChat.time));

console.log(sortedMap.entries())
//Output : MapIterator {'0002' => {…}, '0001' => {…}}
```

If lastChat can be null then you'd need to expand the sort function with additional logic for this.

Comment: Thank you! You really solved my problem!