# Sort a Javascript Map by value numerically

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting, collections, key-value

If `kv` is a Javascript `Map` object, how can I sort it by its value numerically?

This is, for example, a common pattern when `kv` is a counter, and we need to see the top-n items with the highest count.

This is distinct from [Is it possible to sort a ES6 map object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158902/is-it-possible-to-sort-a-es6-map-object) , which is lexical sort.

Comment: This is not distinct from the question you linked. Your sorting will depend on what you pass to `.sort`.

Comment: and [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063007/how-to-sort-an-array-of-integers-correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the first argument in the [`Array.prototype.sort()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

An example for your case would be:

`[...kv.values()].sort((a, b) => a - b);`

Explanation:

1. You obtain the the Value Iterator for your Map object using [`Map.prototype.values()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values)
2. Then you spread it using `[...iterator]` pattern to convert it into an array
3. Last you use the sort function with [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). The first parameter allow you to pass in a comparator function, where:

| `compareFn(a, b)` return value | sort order |
| --- | --- |
| `> 0` | sort `a` after `b`, e.g. `[b, a]` |
| `< 0` | sort `a` before `b`, e.g. `[a, b]` |
| `=== 0` | keep original order of `a` and `b` |