# Javascript sort not returning correct order numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using sort() to filter a list with data including numbers, but with the numbers there's an issue, larger numbers are sorted at the top rather at the bottom.

The lists are not always numbers.

```
<ul class="fliter-container">
    <li data-filter="100 x 10"> 100 x 10 </li>
    <li data-filter="101 11"> 101 x 11 </li>
    <li data-filter="109"> 109 </li>
    <li data-filter="someword"> someword </li>
    <li data-filter="17"> 17 </li>
    <li data-filter="18"> 18 </li>
    <li data-filter="my filter"> my filter </li>
    <li data-filter="19"> 19 </li>
</ul>

$('.filter-container').each(function(){

    var mylist    = $(this);
    var listitems = mylist.children('[data-filter]').get();

    listitems.sort(function(a, b) {

       return $(a).attr('data-filter').toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).attr('data-filter').toUpperCase() , undefined, {numeric: true, sensitivity: 'base'});

    });

    $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { 
       mylist.append(itm); 
    });

});
```

**UPDATED: I have updated my code, found the solution here [Javascript : natural sort of alphanumerical strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings)**

Comment: You're sorting strings, not numbers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165/how-to-sort-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: User `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to convert the string values to number before/during comparison.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: given the new information you *just later* added to your post (i.e. values can also be non-numbers), of course this answer is no longer valid...

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

You're sorting strings, not numbers. If you want to keep them as strings, modify the place in your sorting when you're assigning them to `x` and `y` to convert them to numbers for the sake of comparison, like this

```
var x = parseInt($(a).attr('data-filter'));
var y = parseInt($(b).attr('data-filter'));
```