# Javascript Unexpected Sorting Order

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Using Chrome Version `66.0.3359.117` (Official Build) (64-bit)

Sorting the below array I'm expecting an item with id = 1 to be at the top, which isn't the case. If I reduce the number of items down to 2, sorting works as expected. Can anyone explain why do I get a non deterministic result here?

```js
     let array = [
          { "id": 1, "path": "01.00.00.00.00.00.00" },
          { "id": 2, "path": "01.02.00.00.00.00.00" },
          { "id": 3, "path": "01.02.03.00.00.00.00" },
          { "id": 4, "path": "01.02.04.00.00.00.00" },
          { "id": 5, "path": "01.02.05.00.00.00.00" },
          { "id": 6, "path": "01.02.06.00.00.00.00" },
          { "id": 7, "path": "01.02.05.07.00.00.00" },
          { "id": 8, "path": "01.02.05.07.08.00.00" },
          { "id": 9, "path": "01.02.05.07.08.09.00" },
          { "id": 10, "path": "01.02.04.10.00.00.00" },
          { "id": 11, "path": "01.02.05.07.08.09.11" },
          { "id": 12, "path": "01.02.04.10.12.00.00" }
        ];
        
        array.sort((f, s) => f.path > s.path);
        console.error("Full", array[0].id);
    
        array = [
          { "id": 1, "path": "01.00.00.00.00.00.00" },
          { "id": 2, "path": "01.02.00.00.00.00.00" }
          //{ "id": 3, "path": "01.02.03.00.00.00.00" },
          //{ "id": 4, "path": "01.02.04.00.00.00.00" },
          //{ "id": 5, "path": "01.02.05.00.00.00.00" },
          //{ "id": 6, "path": "01.02.06.00.00.00.00" },
          //{ "id": 7, "path": "01.02.05.07.00.00.00" },
          //{ "id": 8, "path": "01.02.05.07.08.00.00" },
          //{ "id": 9, "path": "01.02.05.07.08.09.00" },
          //{ "id": 10, "path": "01.02.04.10.00.00.00" },
          //{ "id": 11, "path": "01.02.05.07.08.09.11" },
          //{ "id": 12, "path": "01.02.04.10.12.00.00" }
        ];
    
        array.sort((f, s) => f.path > s.path);
        console.error("Reduced", array[0].id);
```

Comment: do you want to sort by id or by path?

Comment: You say you sort by id, but you dont

Comment: If it's worth anything, on Firefox 59 the results are as you are expecting them, i.e. the first item does have `id: 1`.

Comment: cheers. @mplungjan thanks for fixing the format.

Comment: Doesn't `sort()` expect you to return a number instead of a boolean? You return true or false, which will be cast to 0 or 1. So you never return -1 or a different negative number, so records will not be sorted correctly if one record belongs before another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165/how-to-sort-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: Please specify if you want to sort by id or by path value. AS I mention before, you need to return a number inside a sort, so if you sort on id, just subtract them. If you want to sort by path though, you need another function to calculate the value, since number order isn't the same as string order. Compare `1000 > 999` and `'1000' > '999'`. So if you need to compare paths, you need to cast the path back to some numerical value. ( I usually use spluit on the dot and multiply the index, so items that start with 01 will be a quadrillion something, etc... )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your sort condition to `f.id - s.id` which is incorrect in your code.

```js
let array = [
  { "id": 1, "path": "01.00.00.00.00.00.00" },
  { "id": 2, "path": "01.02.00.00.00.00.00" },
  { "id": 3, "path": "01.02.03.00.00.00.00" },
  { "id": 4, "path": "01.02.04.00.00.00.00" },
  { "id": 5, "path": "01.02.05.00.00.00.00" },
  { "id": 6, "path": "01.02.06.00.00.00.00" },
  { "id": 7, "path": "01.02.05.07.00.00.00" },
  { "id": 8, "path": "01.02.05.07.08.00.00" },
  { "id": 9, "path": "01.02.05.07.08.09.00" },
  { "id": 10, "path": "01.02.04.10.00.00.00" },
  { "id": 11, "path": "01.02.05.07.08.09.11" },
  { "id": 12, "path": "01.02.04.10.12.00.00" }
];

array.sort((f, s) => f.id - s.id);
console.error("Full", array[0].id);
```

Comment: that works, still curious'ed as to why do I get different results for the same inputs?

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide 3 options

```
array.sort((f, s) => {
  if(f.path < s.path){return -1}
  if(f.path > s.path){return 1} 
  return 0;
});
```

Basically js comparing function needs to return an integer, since '>' returns a boolean, then true == 1 and false == 0, so when false is returned it is interpreted as the elements are equal, instead of -1 one is maller than the other.

Comment: Should be the same as `return s.path - f.path`, no?

Comment: @mplungjan no, js cant convert "00.20.10" to number, therefore it returns NaN

Comment: Ah - I can test < or > since that is in ascii order, I actually thought it would work with "subtraction" too, but never had to try it. Works on ID though

Answer (score 0):

First, you are comparing two string as like they are numbers, so I think the compiler transforms the string to numbers and then compare them when you do :

```
f.path > s.path
```

Comment: hehe - why does it do differently for 2 arrays?:)

Comment: this is the logic you are comparing two strings as they were numbers, so you will see some unexpected behaviors

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting by `path`, not `id`.

Try `array.sort((f, s) => f.id - s.id);`