# How to sort cell names like A1, A2, A10 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have to sort cell names like this :

```
A1
A2
A3
A10
```

What I tried  with this wrong order :

```
A1
A10
A2
A3
```

Code :

```
var cells = [ 'A1' 'A10', 'A2', 'A3' ];

function mysort(a,b) {
    return a.substr(0,1) - b.substr(0,1) && a.substr(1) - b.substr(1);
}

cells = cells.sort(mysort);
```

or

```
cells = cells.sort();
```

Any clue ?

Comment: How about you try to extract numeric part, treat it as number and then try sorting?

Comment: Probably a better duplicate: [How to sort strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165/how-to-sort-strings-in-javascript) (At least one with easier to read answers and much more upvotes on the question)