# How to modify this sort code for dashed cell names?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I use this code, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056619):

```
var reA = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
var reN = /[^0-9]/g;

function sortAlphaNum(a, b) {
        var aA = a.replace(reA, "");
        var bA = b.replace(reA, "");
        if (aA === bA) {
            var aN = parseInt(a.replace(reN, ""), 10);
            var bN = parseInt(b.replace(reN, ""), 10);
            return aN === bN ? 0 : aN > bN ? 1 : -1;
        } else {
            return aA > bA ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }
```

But what I try to sort is a bit more complex :

I have :

```
A1
A3
A5
A14
A6-1
A6-2
```

I expect :

```
A1
A3
A5
A6-1
A6-2
A14
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you want to sort by the letter first, then by the first number, and then, in order, by the numbers following, separated by `-`? Also, will there be one `-` at most, or might there be more than one `-`?

Comment: Nothing more that what I show here. Correct

Comment: What are `reA` and `reN`?

Comment: Sorry, missing : `var reA = /[^A-Z]/g; var reN = /[^0-9]/g;` I don't have reputation points to edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the reference of  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4340339/4225796 and thanks to @Leonid Pyrlia and as per your question you have refereed same so using the same example for reference,
we can remove the - and number after - by   str.replace(/-.*/g, "");

```js
var reA = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
var reN = /[^0-9]/g;
var removeDash = /-.*/g;

var arr = ['A5','A3','A1','A14','A6-2','A6-1'];

console.log(arr.sort(sortAlphaNum));

function sortAlphaNum(a, b) {

a= a.replace(removeDash, "");
b= b.replace(removeDash, "");

  var aA = a.replace(reA, "");
  var bA = b.replace(reA, "");
  if (aA === bA) {
    var aN = parseInt(a.replace(reN, ""), 10);
    var bN = parseInt(b.replace(reN, ""), 10);
    return aN === bN ? 0 : aN > bN ? 1 : -1;
  } else {
    return aA > bA ? 1 : -1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can break it down into 3 sorting criteria: 1) by first character 2) by second number 3) by optional third number (after the dash `-`) :

```js
const arr = ['A5','A3','A1','A14','A6-2','A6-1'];

const sorted = arr.sort((a,b) => {

  const [[aChar, aN1, aN2],[bChar, bN1, bN2]] = [a,b].map(x => x.match(/([A-Z])|([0-9]+)/gi).map(el => Number(el) || el));

  const c1 = aChar.localeCompare(bChar);
  const c2 = aN1 - bN1;
  const c3 = (aN2 || 0) - (bN2 || 0);

  return c1 || c2 || c3;

});

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand the logic, seems better, but I prefer a readable solution

Comment: @Mévatlavé Kraspek `'A6-1'.match(/([A-Z])|([0-9]+)/gi).map(el => Number(el) || el)` this will convert string `A6-1` into an array `['A', 6, 1]`, or `'A1'` into `['A', 1]`

Comment: This part `[[aChar, aN1, aN2],[bChar, bN1, bN2]]` is an ES6 Array Destructuring assignment. In our compare function, If `a` is `A6-1`, and `b` is `A1`, then respectively that assignment allows us to declare those vars in on line

Comment: Considering all the above-mentioned, `[[aChar, aN1, aN2],[bChar, bN1, bN2]] = [['A', 6, 1], ['A', 1]]`, `aChar` will be equal to `A`, `bChar` - `A`, `aN1` - 6, `bN1` - 1, `aN2` - 1, `bN2` - `undefined` (since there is no third number after dash)

Comment: All of that allows us to break it all down into separate criteria: for character comparison we use `localeCompare` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare; for numeric - simple subtraction (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description)

Comment: Better edit your post with this relevant informations :)

Comment: @Mévatlavé Kraspek ++