# Find letters in random string exactly, using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, string, algorithm

The emphasis here is on the word *exactly*. This needs to work for any number of permutations, so hopefully my example is clear enough.

Given a string of random letters, is it possible (using RegEx) to match an exact number of letters within the given string?

So if I have a string (`str1`) containing letters `ABZBABJDCDAZ` and I wanted to match the letters `JDBBAA` (`str2`), my function should return `true` because `str1` contains all the right letters *enough* times. If however `str1` were to be changed to `ABAJDCDA`, then the function would return `false` as `str2` requires that `str1` have at least *2* instances of the letter `B`.

This is what I have so far using a range:

```js
const findLetters = (str1, str2) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`[${str2}]`, 'g')
  const result = (str1.match(regex))
  console.log(result)
}

findLetters('ABZBABJDCDAZ', 'JDBBAA')
```

As you can see it matches the right letters, but it matches *all* instances of them. Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do using RegEx? The reason I'm focusing on RegEx here is because I need this code to be highly optimised, and so far my other functions using `Array.every()` and `indexOf()` are just too slow.

Note: My function only requires to return a `true/false` value.

Comment: You'd probably need to put a lot of [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): [`^(?=[^J]*J)(?=[^D]*D)`...](https://regex101.com/r/WovUjc/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble Thank you for your comment. I did think of this, but considering `str2` could be 1000 characters long or more, a very large RegEx pattern would have to be generated, which probably would slow the whole thing down a lot. Can you think of a very fast way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve without RegEx? I'm really scratching my head on this one!

Comment: I like the idea of Kamil's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try (here we sort letters of both strings and then create regexp like `A.*A.*B.*B.*D.*J`)

```js
const findLetters = (str1, str2) => {
  const regex = new RegExp([...str2].sort().join`.*`)
  return regex.test([...str1].sort().join``)
}

console.log( findLetters('ABZBABJDCDAZ', 'JDBBAA') );
console.log( findLetters('ABAJDCDA', 'JDBBAA') );
```

Comment: Very ingenious! Thank you :)

Comment: @JossClassey If you need to optimize performance, you could probably play with the pattern and optimize to somewhat like `AA.*?BB.*?D.*?J`. Nice answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if regex is the right way for this as this can also get very expensive. Regex is fast, but not always the fastest.

```js
const findLetters2 = (strSearchIn, strSearchFor) => {
  var strSearchInSorted = strSearchIn.split('').sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
  });
  var strSearchForSorted = strSearchFor.split('').sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
  });

  return hasAllChars(strSearchInSorted, strSearchForSorted);
}

const hasAllChars = (searchInCharList, searchCharList) => {
  var counter = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < searchCharList.length; i++) {
    var found = false;
    for (counter; counter < searchInCharList.length;) {
      counter++;
      if (searchCharList[i] == searchInCharList[counter - 1]) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (found == false) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

// No-Regex solution
console.log('true: ' + findLetters2('abcABC', 'abcABC'));
console.log('true: ' + findLetters2('abcABC', 'acbACB'));
console.log('true: ' + findLetters2('abcABCx', 'acbACB'));
console.log('false: ' + findLetters2('abcABC', 'acbACBx'));
console.log('true: ' + findLetters2('ahfffmbbbertwcAtzrBCasdf', 'acbACB'));
console.log('false: ' + findLetters2('abcABC', 'acbAACB'));
```

Feel free to test it's speed and to optimize it as I'm no js expert. This solution should iterate each string once after sorting. Sorting is thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51169/9338645.