# A stable/neutral/culture insensitive locale in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, locale

I would like to have a stable, well defined sort order in Javascript.

It could be any defined locale, but the point is to have the code say
"just some neutral sort order used here".

Java and C# have their [Neutral culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.8#Invariant) and [ROOT](https://coderanch.com/t/594833/java/ROOT-locale) [locales](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#ROOT) which have
been used for this purpose.

[The Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Locale_identification_and_negotiation) does not at least immediately seem to
offer such options.

Comment: When you say sort order, how do you sort for the locale to come into play — by using localeCompare?

Comment: @IngoBürk yes. I'm trying to use localeCompare. I noticed that there are other options that could be set

Comment: the neutral standard is not to use some locales.

Comment: What do you consider "neutral"? Just use the standard string comparison, which is well-defined and culture-insensitive.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I mean precisely that. I didn't know/remember that `<` applies to strings. The sort order is the same as with `sort()` on strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bergi pointed out above, in many cases you can just use `<` on strings and it is well defined and culture insensitive.

Say for using some kind of custom sort something like this would work:

```
["foo", "bar"].sort((a, b)=> a < b ? -1 : 1)
```

(in that simple case `.sort()` would of course be equivalent and simpler.)

Answer (score 1):

My answer is to use `"en"` with [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Based on my tests below, `en` produces the most consistent results.

Here is an example of using that with `localeCompare`:

```
"å".localeCompare("ä", "en")
```

By my understanding `und` (short for undetermined)
(and maybe `en-US-u-va-posix`) should be better answers to the original question, but the `und` seems to behave differently in
Firefox (and the behavior of `en-US-u-va-posix` in NodeJS depends on the presence of the ICU-data).

Perhaps if you are not hitting the Firefox problem, consider
using `und` or just the parameterless form to convey the
idea that the locale is not important

Some related things I learned while researching this (adding them here just in case somebody else is heading down the same rabbit hole):

- [This very popular answer about using `localeCompare`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51169/1148030) with lots of useful comments.
- From [this old post](http://unicode.org/pipermail/cldr-users/2014-September/000143.html) I learned that there are some "special" locales.
- With older browsers there may be no hope. Quoting the Mozilla documentation: "In older implementations, which ignore the locales and options arguments, the locale and sort order used are entirely implementation dependent."
- NodeJS seems to use the [Project ICU icu4c library](http://site.icu-project.org/repository) under the hood for locale related functionality.
- The icu-project has this online [tool to experiment with collation orders](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/collation.html).
- the plain sort() is different from the other options, but seems stable across the platforms I tested.
- The characters  were triggering some kind of bug on older version of NodeJS
- The locale data is not present in my node installation [and installing the icu data](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4067#issuecomment-164093076) makes the `localeCompare` have different behavior.

Here is the test code I ended up using:

```
const testArray=["Ă","Â","Î","Ș","Ț","A","i","I","S","T","é","e","ä","a","","","Д","д", "å", "z"]
const locales=["POSIX", "en-US-u-va-posix", "und", "en", "da", "ru"]

console.log(`${testArray.sort().join("")} sort()`)

console.log(`${testArray.sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b)).join("")} localeCompare(x)`)

locales.forEach(locale => {
    const f = (a,b) => a.localeCompare(b, locale)
    try{
        console.log(`${testArray.sort(f).join("")} ${locale}`)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(`${locale}: ${e}`)
    }
})
```

On my Mac with NodeJS 13.5.0 with full-icu I get this output:

```
AISTaeizÂÎäåéĂȘȚДд sort()
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД localeCompare(x)
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД POSIX
AĂÂIÎSȘTȚaåäeéizдД en-US-u-va-posix
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД und
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД en
AaĂÂeéIiÎSȘTȚzäåДд da
дДaAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚz ru
```

Node v12.14.0 gets the same result.

Without the NODE_ICU_DATA, v12.14.0 gives:

```
AISTaeizÂÎäåéĂȘȚДд sort()
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД localeCompare(x)
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД POSIX
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД en-US-u-va-posix
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД und
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД en
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД da
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД ru
```

My Chrome browser gives this result:

```
AISTaeizÂÎäåéĂȘȚДд sort()
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД localeCompare(x)
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД POSIX
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД en-US-u-va-posix
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД und
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД en
AaĂÂeéIiÎSȘTȚzäåДд da
дДaAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚz ru
```

The Safari browser on my mac gives the same except for `da`:

```
aAĂÂeéiIÎSȘTȚzäåдД da
```

Firefox on my mac gives this somewhat different result:

```
AISTaeizÂÎäåéĂȘȚДд sort()
aAĂÂeéiIÎSȘTȚzåäдД localeCompare(x)
aAĂÂeéiIÎSȘTȚzåäдД POSIX
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД en-US-u-va-posix
aAĂÂeéiIÎSȘTȚzåäдД und
aAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚzдД en
AaĂÂeéIiÎSȘTȚzäåДд da
дДaAĂÂåäeéiIÎSȘTȚz ru
```

There is also the function `Intl.getCanonicalLocales`. Here are some results I found testing that:

```
$ node
> Intl.getCanonicalLocales("en-US-POSIX")
[ 'en-US-u-va-posix' ]
```

- On recent Chrome it works as above in NodeJS
- On recent Safari getCanonicalLocales seems to accept almost any string and returns that string
- Recent Firefox is the same as recent Safari