# Javascript array sort for regular strings and strings of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that could be either just a list of strings or it could be just a list of strings of numbers, i.e array could be like below

```
let array = ['abc','def','aef','gfh']
             or
let array = ['123','456','192','412']
```

I want to have sort function that can handle the natural sort in either of these case, below code doesn't seem to handle the string of numbers, is there a way to handle this?

```
    array.sort((a,b) => {
        if(a > b) return 1;
        if(a < b) return -1;
        return 0;
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165/how-to-sort-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`String#localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method like:

```js
let array = ['abc', 'def', 'aef', 'gfh']
array.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true }));
console.log(array)

array = ['123', '456', '192', '412', '5']
array.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true }));
console.log(array)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Numeric_sorting), for numeric sorting we just need to use `{numeric: true}` option.

```js
// by default, "2" > "10"
console.log(["2", "10"].sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b))); // ["10", "2"]

// numeric using options:
console.log(["2", "10"].sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true})));
// ["2", "10"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. This is what I needed. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether the element in the `array` is a number or a string in the `sort` function.

The `isNaN(string)` check would tell you if it is not a number:

```js
function sortNumOrStr(array) {
  return array.sort((a, b) => isNaN(a) ? a.localeCompare(b) : +a - b);
}

let array = ['abc', 'def', 'aef', 'gfh']
console.log(sortNumOrStr(array));
array =  ['123', '456', '-90', '192', '412'];
console.log(sortNumOrStr(array));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. This is what I needed. :)