# how to sort alpha/numeric array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

This is my array

```
var a=[{name:'ABC125', sName: 'sadf'},{name:'ABC12', sName: 'sadf'},{name:'ABC15', sName: 'sadf'},{name:'Sbc125', sName: 'sadf'},{name:'pcb125', sName: 'sadf'}];
```

my Code for sort is

```
a.sort((x,y)=>(x.name.toLowerCase() > y.name.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : -1)
```

but this returns me as

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165/how-to-sort-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: what  you want to achieve? or desired output please

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: expected- see in image 2nd index object is to be at 1st index after 0th index

Comment: Do you want to sort using numbers only?

Comment: Please, explain a little what's you're trying to accomplish and post the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.sort((x, y) => x.name.localeCompare(y.name, 'en', { numeric: true }))
```

Comment: How do you know the OP wants a sorting approach with numbers only? and more than that, you didn't even explain your answer.

Comment: OP = Original poster - [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
var content=[
{name:'ABC125', sName: 'sadf'},
{name:'ABC12', sName: 'sadf'},
{name:'ABC15', sName: 'sadf'},
{name:'Sbc125', sName: 'sadf'},
{name:'pcb125', sName: 'sadf'}
];


content.sort(function (a, b) {
    return ('' + a.attr).localeCompare(b.attr);
})



console.log(content)
```

output will be

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "ABC125", sName: "sadf"}
1: {name: "ABC12", sName: "sadf"}
2: {name: "ABC15", sName: "sadf"}
3: {name: "Sbc125", sName: "sadf"}
4: {name: "pcb125", sName: "sadf"}
```

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51169/3046937

There is already answer exists here
[Javascript : natural sort of alphanumerical strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings)