# sorting a list alphabetically is not sorting anything at all

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to take a list of cars and sort them alphabetically.

So I found this method to sort:

```
let cars = this.state.cars;

cars.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.carName < b.carName) { return -1; }
    if (a.carName > b.carName) { return 1; }
    return 0;
})
console.log("items after sort: ", cars);
```

But when I write it out to the console, you can see the results below and they are not alphabetically sorted.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
items after sort: 
List {size: 431, _origin: 0, _level: 5, _root: VNode, …}
size: 431
__altered: true
_level: 5
_origin: 0
_root: VNode
array: Array(4)
0: VNode {array: Array(32)}
    0: {id: 1, carName: "Ford", isLocal: false, …}
    1: {id: 2, carName: "BMW", isLocal: true, …}
    2: {id: 3, carName: "Audi", isLocal: false,…}
    3: {id: 4, carName: "Toyota", isLocal: false,…}

1: VNode {array: Array(32)}
2: VNode {array: Array(32)}
3: VNode {array: Array(32)}
```

Comment: I believe there should be an answer about this check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165/how-to-sort-strings-in-javascript/51169

Comment: @halilcakar that is actually the same Stack Overflow question I found my solution that doesn't work

Comment: I [can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/40Lrwpdv/) your issue ...?

Comment: try this it should work ``cars.sort( (a,b) => a.carName > b.carName ? 1 : -1)``

Comment: @Teemu I think your list of cars is set up more simply than mine.  I think my list is different in that it has something called a VNode that contains the array.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell That's the information you've provided. If you've sorted a different array, then you have found your mistake ... Notice, that in the code example you've `let cars = this.state.cars`, there's no `state` nor `cars` in the logged content.

Comment: @Teemu yeah I don't know why either, I see no errors though, so doesn't that mean it's finding the cars to sort?  Like if `cars.carName` did not exist would it not give me an error?  Thanks!

Comment: No, it won't throw an error, it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your log seems to imply that this data is from immutable.js.

By definition the data structure is .. immutable (*cannot be modified*). So running `sort` on it will not modify the existing data but will return a sorted copy.

So try something like

```
let cars = this.state.cars;

const sortedCars = cars.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.carName < b.carName) { return -1; }
    if (a.carName > b.carName) { return 1; }
    return 0;
})
console.log("items after sort: ", sortedCars);
```

or you could convert to normal js data structures with `.toJS()` and then do what you want.

```
let cars = this.state.cars.toJS();
cars.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.carName < b.carName) { return -1; }
    if (a.carName > b.carName) { return 1; }
    return 0;
})
console.log("items after sort: ", cars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest possible code with ES6!

```
users.sort((a, b) => a. carName.localeCompare(b. carName))
```

[String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Browser_compatibility) basic support is universal!