# How do I find the "max" string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Similar to [How to sort strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165/how-to-sort-strings-in-javascript) but I want to avoid sorting first, I just want the "largest" value of a string.  For example

```
f(['Aa', 'B', 'C', 'Acd', 'Ace']) == 'C'
```

I am thinking it's something with `.reduce` like

```js
const f = (a) => a.reduce(someFunctionGoesHere)
```

Where some function has an `undefined` check

UPDATE: Got it working but looks fugly.  I wonder if I can reduce that function

```
const someFunctionGoesHere = (prev, current) => {
  if (!prev) {
    return current;
  }
  else if (prev.localeCompare(current) < 0) {
    return current;
  } else {
    return prev;
  }
};
const f = (a) => a.reduce(someFunctionGoesHere)

console.log(f(['Aa', 'B', 'C', 'Acd', 'Ace','CC']));
```

UPDATE: this works, one line, but looks quite ugly.  I guess this is the best that can be done with Javascript itself.

```
const maxString = (a) => a.reduce((prev, current) => (!prev || prev.localeCompare(current) < 0) ? current : prev)

console.log(maxString(['Aa', 'B', 'C', 'Acd', 'Ace','CC']));
```

Comment: You already have reduce function. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You can give a default value in `array#reduce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, `reduce()` will get you there:

```js
const f = (array) => array.reduce((a, v) => v.localeCompare(a) > 0 ? v : a, '');

console.log(f(['Aa', 'B', 'C', 'Acd', 'Ace','CC']));
```

Comment: `localeCompare` returns a number. Your condition only false when `v` and `a` are equal.

Comment: @RickyMo Thanks, updated. Looks like I need more coffee :)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen same here.  I thought and proven again that sometimes articulating what you want makes the answer come out more naturally.