# How to do case insensitive string comparison?

Tags: javascript, string

How do I perform case insensitive string comparison in JavaScript?

Comment: see the newly added `.localeCompare()` javascript method. Only supported by modern browsers at the time of writting (IE11+). see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: @AdrienBe `"A".localeCompare( "a" );` returns `1` in the Chrome 48 Console.

Comment: @manuell `localeCompare` does case insensitive comparison if you pass the `{ sensitivity: 'accent' }` or `{ sensitivity: 'base' }` option. `"A".localeCompare("a", undefined, { sensitivity: 'accent' }) === 0`.

Answer (score 1523, accepted):

EDIT: *This answer was originally added over 10 years ago. Today should use localeCompare.  See the other answers.*

The simplest way to do it (if you're not worried about special Unicode characters) is to call `toUpperCase`:

```
var areEqual = string1.toUpperCase() === string2.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Conversion to upper or lower case does provide correct case insensitive comparisons in all languages.  http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html

Comment: @sam: I know.  That's why I wrote `if you're not worried about special Unicode characters`.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer `toUpperCase` over `toLowerCase`?

Comment: @jpmc26: Yes; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E

Comment: What do you mean by "if you're not worried about special Unicode characters" ? what is the effect of toUpperCase on this characters ?

Comment: @Kugel This answer is 9 years old. There is new functionality since then so as of the date of your comment, no, it is not the best JS has to offer. See below answer on `localeCompare` which was updated more recently (but still five years ago). I'm not aware of anything that has changed in the last five years that would make `localeCompare` no longer the best answer.

Comment: 'ß'.toUpperCase() transforms the string to `SS`. Wow, not expected. In my opinion the `ß` should not be changed. But for this I prefer toLowerCase() for case insensitive check.

Comment: @SLaks: I don't get the MS argument for `toUpperCase` mentioning "roundtripping". Neither ẞ (upper case), nor ß (lowercase) makes it through a roundtrip. So how a prefererence for one or the other is derived from this?

Comment: Can there be a community effort to make this not the first/accepted answer, since it is just *wrong*. And only correct in a very specific circumstance instead of the generic one.

Comment: And if you're not worried about unnecessary allocations...

Answer (score 360):

**EDIT**: This answer was originally added 9 years ago. Today you should use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) with the `sensitivity: 'accent'` option:

```js
function ciEquals(a, b) {
    return typeof a === 'string' && typeof b === 'string'
        ? a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { sensitivity: 'accent' }) === 0
        : a === b;
}

console.log("'a' = 'a'?", ciEquals('a', 'a'));
console.log("'AaA' = 'aAa'?", ciEquals('AaA', 'aAa'));
console.log("'a' = 'á'?", ciEquals('a', 'á'));
console.log("'a' = 'b'?", ciEquals('a', 'b'));
```

The `{ sensitivity: 'accent' }` tells `localeCompare()` to treat two variants of the same base letter as the same *unless* they have different accents (as in the third example) above.

Alternatively, you can use `{ sensitivity: 'base' }`, which treats two characters as equivalent as long as their base character is the same (so `A` would be treated as equivalent to `á`).

**Note** that the third parameter of `localeCompare` is not supported in IE10 or lower or certain mobile browsers (see the compatibility chart on the page linked above), so if you need to support those browsers, you'll need some kind of fallback:

```
function ciEqualsInner(a, b) {
    return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { sensitivity: 'accent' }) === 0;
}

function ciEquals(a, b) {
    if (typeof a !== 'string' || typeof b !== 'string') {
        return a === b;
    }

    //      v--- feature detection
    return ciEqualsInner('A', 'a')
        ? ciEqualsInner(a, b)
        : /*  fallback approach here  */;
}
```

*Original answer*

The best way to do a case insensitive comparison in JavaScript is to use RegExp `match()` method with the `i` flag.

[Case-insensitive search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177719/javascript-case-insensitive-search)

When both strings being compared are variables (not constants), then it's a little more complicated 'cause you need to generate a RegExp from the string but passing the string to RegExp constructor can result in incorrect matches or failed matches if the string has special regex characters in it.

If you care about internationalization don't use `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` as it doesn't provide accurate case-insensitive comparisons in all languages.

http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/turkish-i18n.html

Comment: @Quandary, yes, that's what I said had to be handled--"you need to generate a RegExp from the string but passing the string to RegExp constructor can result in incorrect matches or failed matches if the string has special regex characters in it"

Comment: Using this is the most costly solution for case-insensitive string comparison. A RegExp is meant for complicated pattern matching, as such, it needs to build a decision tree for each pattern, then executes that against input strings. While it would work, it is comparable to taking a jet airplane to go shopping on the next block.
tl;dr: please don't do this.

Comment: i could use localeCompare(), but its returning -1 for `'a'.localeCompare('A')` and like the op I'm looking for case insensitive string compare.

Comment: @StingyJack to do case-insensitive compare using localeCompare, you should do 'a'.localeCompare('A', undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' })

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the addition! Do you have a link/reference for what browsers do or do not support this API? I'm curious how applicable this is in practice.

Comment: **Note:** The `localeCompare` version requires that the JavaScript engine support the [ECMAScript® Internationalization API](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/6.0/index.html), which it is **not** required to do. So before relying on it, you might want to check that it works in the environment you're using. For instance: `const compareInsensitive = "x".localeCompare("X", undefined, {sensitivity: "base"}) === 0 ? (a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {sensitivity: "base"}) : (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());` or some such.

Comment: @SamuelNeff - Primarily mobile: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare (there was a copy/paste error in my original comment, so I deleted it and reposted a corrected version, which is why it's now below your question about it :-) ).

Comment: Keep in mind that `localeCompare` is much slower than `string1.toUpperCase() === string2.toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 166):

As said in recent comments, [`string::localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) supports case insensitive comparisons (among other powerful things).

Here's a simple example

```
'xyz'.localeCompare('XyZ', undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' }); // returns 0
```

And a generic function you could use

```
function equalsIgnoringCase(text, other) {
    return text.localeCompare(other, undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' }) === 0;
}
```

Note that instead of `undefined` you should probably enter the specific locale you are working with. This is important as denoted in the MDN docs

> in Swedish, ä and a are separate base letters

### Sensitivity options

[image: Sensitivity options tabulated from MDN]

### Browser support

As of time of posting, UC Browser for Android and Opera Mini *do not* support *locale* and *options* parameters. Please check https://caniuse.com/#search=localeCompare for up to date info.

Comment: As I'm fairly sure browsers don't regularly _remove_ support for features from older versions, the Browser support listed here is incorrect or at least incomplete (according to your caniuse link). IE < 11, Firefox < 29, Chrome < 24, and Safari < 10 (just to list the popular browsers) also do not support the `locale` and `options` parameters, and most likely didn't when this answer was posted. This is probably far more useful for new readers than the obscure browsers listed that basically don't support any somewhat modern features.

Answer (score 54):

#### Update:

As per the comments, previous answer checks for `source contains keyword`, to make it equality check added `^` and `$`.

```js
(/^keyword$/i).test(source)
```

---

With the help of regular expression also we can achieve.

```
(/keyword/i).test(source)
```

`/i` is for ignoring case. If not necessary we can ignore and test for NOT case sensitive matches like

```
(/keyword/).test(source)
```

Comment: Using a regex like this will match substrings!

In your example the string `keyWORD` will indead result in a positive match. But the string `this is a keyword yo` or `keywords` will also result in a positive match.

Be aware of that :-)

Comment: This does not answer the **Equality** check (case insensitive) as asked in the question! But, this is a **Contains** check! Don't use it

Comment: Of course, to match the entire string, the regexp can be changed into `/^keyword$/.test(source)`, but 1) if `keyword` is not a constant, you'd need to do `new RegExp('^' + x + '$').test(source)` and 2) resorting to a regexp to test something as simple as case-insensitive string equality is not at all very efficient.

Comment: const regexpEqual = (a, b) =>  (new RegExp(`^${a}$`, "gi")).test(b)

Answer (score 35):

Remember that casing is a locale specific operation. Depending on scenario you may want to take that in to account. For example, if you are comparing names of two people you may want to consider locale but if you are comparing machine generated values such as UUID then you might not. This why I use following function in my utils library (note that type checking is not included for performance reason).

```
function compareStrings (string1, string2, ignoreCase, useLocale) {
    if (ignoreCase) {
        if (useLocale) {
            string1 = string1.toLocaleLowerCase();
            string2 = string2.toLocaleLowerCase();
        }
        else {
            string1 = string1.toLowerCase();
            string2 = string2.toLowerCase();
        }
    }

    return string1 === string2;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use "!!" to perform an explicit boolean conversion, instead of allowing the if clause to evaluate the truthiness of the values?

Comment: It's not required. I guess I had it from my other version of more complicated code. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @thekodester your function has a bug. This `compareStrings("", "")` will give `false` in spite the fact the strings are equal.

Comment: @Sergey Doing that returns `true` for me. Perhaps it is a bug with your browser?

Comment: Locale is definitely an important factor to consider. +1

Answer (score 14):

if you are concerned about the direction of the inequality (perhaps you want to sort a list)
you pretty-much have to do case-conversion, and as there are more lowercase characters in unicode than uppercase toLowerCase is probably the best conversion to use.

```
function my_strcasecmp( a, b ) 
{
    if((a+'').toLowerCase() > (b+'').toLowerCase()) return 1  
    if((a+'').toLowerCase() < (b+'').toLowerCase()) return -1
    return 0
}
```

Javascript seems to use locale "C" for string comparisons so the resulting ordering will
be ugly if the strings contain other than ASCII letters. there's not much that can be done about that without doing much more detailed inspection of the strings.

Answer (score 13):

I have recently created a micro library that provides case-insensitive string helpers: https://github.com/nickuraltsev/ignore-case. (It uses `toUpperCase` internally.)

```
var ignoreCase = require('ignore-case');

ignoreCase.equals('FOO', 'Foo'); // => true
ignoreCase.startsWith('foobar', 'FOO'); // => true
ignoreCase.endsWith('foobar', 'BaR'); // => true
ignoreCase.includes('AbCd', 'c'); // => true
ignoreCase.indexOf('AbCd', 'c'); // => 2
```

Answer (score 8):

Use RegEx for string match or comparison.

In JavaScript, you can use `match()` for string comparison,
don't forget to put `i` in the regular expression. This flag will force case insensitive testing.

Example:

To confirm the string `test` of any case is included anywhere inside the `matchString` variable

```
var matchString = "Test";
if (matchString.match(/test/i)) {
    alert('matchString contains the substring "test" case insensitive');
}
else {
    alert('matchString does not contain the substring "test" case insensitive');
}
```

To confirm `matchString` variable only contains `test` of any case, and no additional characters, then use zero-width assertions `^` and `$` in the regular expression. These will require `test` to appear directly after the start of the string and directly before the end of the string respecitivly.

```
var matchString = "Test";
if (matchString.match(/^test$/i)) {
    alert('matchString equals "test" case insensitive');
}
else {
    alert('matchString does not equal "test" case insensitive');
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're okay with partial matches, otherwise `matchString.match(/^test$/i)`.

Comment: What is instead of  lowercase"test" you have var x = 'test', would `matchString.match(/x/i)` work? If not, what would work?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir , In case of dynamic pattern, you can use RegExp Object
Ex: var x = new RegExp(/test/, "gi"); 
matchString.match(x);

Comment: Or ``const x_regex = new RegExp(`^${x}$`, "gi");``, though that's messy.

Comment: bad performance with regex

Comment: @serge, given the relative simplicity of the use case I agree regex might not be the fastest solution. However if the use case expands then a regex might preform better than a custom built function, or looping through multiple equivalency tests.  For example how do I test if the string contains one substring of an array of strings.

Comment: const regexpEqual = (a, b) =>  (new RegExp(`^${a}$`, "gi")).test(b)

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways for case insensitive comparison:

1. Convert strings to upper case and then compare them using the strict operator (`===`).
2. Pattern matching using string methods:

Use the "search" string method for case insensitive search.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    // 1st way

    var a = "apple";
    var b = "APPLE";
    if (a.toUpperCase() === b.toUpperCase()) {
      alert("equal");
    }

    //2nd way

    var a = " Null and void";
    document.write(a.search(/null/i));
  </script>
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

Suppose we want to find the string variable `needle` in the string variable `haystack`. There are three gotchas:

1. Internationalized applications should avoid `string.toUpperCase` and `string.toLowerCase`. Use a regular expression which ignores case instead. For example, `var needleRegExp = new RegExp(needle, "i");` followed by `needleRegExp.test(haystack)`.
2. In general, you might not know the value of `needle`. Be careful that `needle` does not contain any regular expression [special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions). Escape these using `needle.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");`.
3. In other cases, if you want to precisely match `needle` and `haystack`, just ignoring case, make sure to add `"^"` at the start and `"$"` at the end of your regular expression constructor.

Taking points (1) and (2) into consideration, an example would be:

```
var haystack = "A. BAIL. Of. Hay.";
var needle = "bail.";
var needleRegExp = new RegExp(needle.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&"), "i");
var result = needleRegExp.test(haystack);
if (result) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: You bet! All you need to do is replace the ```new RegExp(...)``` part in line 3 with the following: ```new RegExp("^" + needle.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&") + "$", "i");```. This makes sure that there are no other characters before or after your search string ```needle```.

Answer (score 7):

Lots of answers here, but I like to add a sollution based on extending the String lib:

```
String.prototype.equalIgnoreCase = function(str)
{
    return (str != null 
            && typeof str === 'string'
            && this.toUpperCase() === str.toUpperCase());
}
```

This way you can just use it like you do in Java!

Example:

```
var a = "hello";
var b = "HeLLo";
var c = "world";

if (a.equalIgnoreCase(b)) {
    document.write("a == b");
}
if (a.equalIgnoreCase(c)) {
    document.write("a == c");
}
if (!b.equalIgnoreCase(c)) {
    document.write("b != c");
}
```

Output will be:

```
"a == b"
"b != c"
```

```js
String.prototype.equalIgnoreCase = function(str) {
  return (str != null &&
    typeof str === 'string' &&
    this.toUpperCase() === str.toUpperCase());
}


var a = "hello";
var b = "HeLLo";
var c = "world";

if (a.equalIgnoreCase(b)) {
  document.write("a == b");
  document.write("<br>");
}
if (a.equalIgnoreCase(c)) {
  document.write("a == c");
}
if (!b.equalIgnoreCase(c)) {
  document.write("b != c");
}
```

Comment: This is the most cleaver solution, and opens the door to so many other operations you might want, but are missing in the language.

Answer (score 6):

If both strings are of the same known locale, you may want to use [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator) object like this:

```
function equalIgnoreCase(s1: string, s2: string) {
    return new Intl.Collator("en-US", { sensitivity: "base" }).compare(s1, s2) === 0;
}
```

Obviously, you may want to cache the `Collator` for better efficiency.

The advantages of this approach is that it should be much faster than using RegExps and is based on an extremely customizable (see description of `locales` and `options` constructor parameters in the article above) set of ready-to-use collators.

Comment: Another option for sensitivity is `accent`, which keeps it case insensitive, but treats `a` and `á` as separate characters. So `base` or `accent` could both be appropriate depending on the exact needs.

Answer (score 5):

I like this quick shorthand variation -

```
export const equalsIgnoreCase = (str1, str2) => {
    return (!str1 && !str2) || (str1 && str2 && str1.toUpperCase() == str2.toUpperCase())
}
```

Quick in processing, and does what it is intended to.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a extension. very trivial

```
if (typeof String.prototype.isEqual!= 'function') {
    String.prototype.isEqual = function (str){
        return this.toUpperCase()==str.toUpperCase();
     };
}
```

Comment: What happens two codebases with different ideas of how String#isEqual should work try to exist at the same time?

Comment: @KhanSharp A lot of people consider it an anti-pattern to modify the prototype of built in types. This is why people might be down voting your answer.

Comment: Isn't it ill-considered to prefer unknown method definitions? For example as soon as some browser decides to implement `String#isEqual` or `Object#isEqual` natively all of your pages behave differently and might do weird things if the specification doesn't match yours exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Even this question has already been answered. I have a different approach to using RegExp and match to ignore case sensitivity. Please see my link
https://jsfiddle.net/marchdave/7v8bd7dq/27/

```
$("#btnGuess").click(guessWord);

function guessWord() {

  var letter = $("#guessLetter").val();
  var word = 'ABC';
  var pattern = RegExp(letter, 'gi'); // pattern: /a/gi

  var result = word.match(pattern);
  alert('Ignore case sensitive:' + result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str = 'Lol', str2 = 'lOl', regex = new RegExp('^' + str + '$', 'i');
if (regex.test(str)) {
    console.log("true");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert both to lower string (only once for performance reasons) and compare them with inline ternary operator:

```
function strcasecmp(s1,s2){
    s1=(s1+'').toLowerCase();
    s2=(s2+'').toLowerCase();
    return s1>s2?1:(s1<s2?-1:0);
}
```

Comment: Who says C is dead? :D

Answer (score 1):

How about NOT throwing exceptions and NOT using slow regex?

```
return str1 != null && str2 != null 
    && typeof str1 === 'string' && typeof str2 === 'string'
    && str1.toUpperCase() === str2.toUpperCase();
```

The above snippet assumes you don't want to match if either string is null or undefined.

If you want to match null/undefined, then:

```
return (str1 == null && str2 == null)
    || (str1 != null && str2 != null 
        && typeof str1 === 'string' && typeof str2 === 'string'
        && str1.toUpperCase() === str2.toUpperCase());
```

If for some reason you care about undefined vs null:

```
return (str1 === undefined && str2 === undefined)
    || (str1 === null && str2 === null)
    || (str1 != null && str2 != null 
        && typeof str1 === 'string' && typeof str2 === 'string'
        && str1.toUpperCase() === str2.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: Or just `str1 == str2 || ...`

Answer (score 1):

Since no answer clearly provided a simple code snippet for using `RegExp`, here's my attempt:

```
function compareInsensitive(str1, str2){ 
  return typeof str1 === 'string' && 
    typeof str2 === 'string' && 
    new RegExp("^" + str1.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "$", "i").test(str2);
}
```

It has several advantages:

1. Verifies parameter type (any non-string parameter, like `undefined` for example, would crash an expression like `str1.toUpperCase()`).
2. Does not suffer from possible internationalization issues.
3. Escapes the `RegExp` string.

Comment: But suffers from lack of regexp escaping.

Comment: @Qwertiy fair point, added escaping per https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/67824.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you're dealing with `ascii` text then you can just use a uppercase/lowercase character offset comparison.

Just make sure the string your "perfect" string (the one you want to match against) is lowercase:

```js
const CHARS_IN_BETWEEN = 32;
const LAST_UPPERCASE_CHAR = 90; // Z
function strMatchesIgnoreCase(lowercaseMatch, value) {
    let i = 0, matches = lowercaseMatch.length === value.length;
    while (matches && i < lowercaseMatch.length) {
        const a = lowercaseMatch.charCodeAt(i);
        const A = a - CHARS_IN_BETWEEN;
        const b = value.charCodeAt(i);
        const B = b + ((b > LAST_UPPERCASE_CHAR) ? -CHARS_IN_BETWEEN : CHARS_IN_BETWEEN);
        matches = a === b // lowerA === b
            || A === b // upperA == b
            || a === B // lowerA == ~b
            || A === B; // upperA == ~b
        i++;
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For better browser compatibility you can rely on a regular expression. This will work in all web browsers released in the last 20 years:

```
String.prototype.equalsci = function(s) {
    var regexp = RegExp("^"+this.replace(/[.\\+*?\[\^\]$(){}=!<>|:-]/g, "\\$&")+"$", "i");
    return regexp.test(s);
}

"PERSON@Ü.EXAMPLE.COM".equalsci("person@ü.example.com")// returns true
```

This is different from the other answers found here because it takes into account that not all users are using modern web browsers.

Note: If you need to support unusual cases like the Turkish language you will need to use localeCompare because i and I are not the same letter in Turkish.

```
"I".localeCompare("i", undefined, { sensitivity:"accent"})===0// returns true
"I".localeCompare("i", "tr", { sensitivity:"accent"})===0// returns false
```

Comment: Might be better to use Object.defineProperty to avoid the equalsci method being enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

This is an **improved version** of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20318795/1844247).

```
String.equal = function (s1, s2, ignoreCase, useLocale) {
    if (s1 == null || s2 == null)
        return false;

    if (!ignoreCase) {
        if (s1.length !== s2.length)
            return false;

        return s1 === s2;
    }

    if (useLocale) {
        if (useLocale.length)
            return s1.toLocaleLowerCase(useLocale) === s2.toLocaleLowerCase(useLocale)
        else
            return s1.toLocaleLowerCase() === s2.toLocaleLowerCase()
    }
    else {
        if (s1.length !== s2.length)
            return false;

        return s1.toLowerCase() === s2.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

---

**Usages & tests:**

```js
String.equal = function (s1, s2, ignoreCase, useLocale) {
    if (s1 == null || s2 == null)
        return false;

    if (!ignoreCase) {
        if (s1.length !== s2.length)
            return false;

        return s1 === s2;
    }

    if (useLocale) {
        if (useLocale.length)
            return s1.toLocaleLowerCase(useLocale) === s2.toLocaleLowerCase(useLocale)
        else
            return s1.toLocaleLowerCase() === s2.toLocaleLowerCase()
    }
    else {
        if (s1.length !== s2.length)
            return false;

        return s1.toLowerCase() === s2.toLowerCase();
    }
}

// If you don't mind extending the prototype.
String.prototype.equal = function(string2, ignoreCase, useLocale) {
  return String.equal(this.valueOf(), string2, ignoreCase, useLocale);
}

// ------------------ TESTS ----------------------
console.log("Tests...");

console.log('Case sensitive 1');
var result = "Abc123".equal("Abc123");
console.assert(result === true);

console.log('Case sensitive 2');
result = "aBC123".equal("Abc123");
console.assert(result === false);

console.log('Ignore case');
result = "AbC123".equal("aBc123", true);
console.assert(result === true);

console.log('Ignore case + Current locale');
result = "AbC123".equal("aBc123", true);
console.assert(result === true);

console.log('Turkish test 1 (ignore case, en-US)');
result = "IiiI".equal("ıiİI", true, "en-US");
console.assert(result === false);

console.log('Turkish test 2 (ignore case, tr-TR)');
result = "IiiI".equal("ıiİI", true, "tr-TR");
console.assert(result === true);

console.log('Turkish test 3 (case sensitive, tr-TR)');
result = "IiiI".equal("ıiİI", false, "tr-TR");
console.assert(result === false);

console.log('null-test-1');
result = "AAA".equal(null);
console.assert(result === false);

console.log('null-test-2');
result = String.equal(null, "BBB");
console.assert(result === false);

console.log('null-test-3');
result = String.equal(null, null);
console.assert(result === false);
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also do this using ASCII:

```
function toLower(a){

    let c = "";

    
    for(let i = 0;i<a.length;i++){

        
        let f = a.charCodeAt(i);
        if(f < 95){

            c += String.fromCharCode(f+32);
        }
        else{

            c += a[i];
        }
    }

    return c;
}
function compareIt(a,b){


    return toLower(a)==toLower(b);


}
console.log(compareIt("An ExamPlE" , "an example"));
```