# Prepending "http://" to a URL that doesn't already contain "http://"

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have an `input` field that saves a URL, I'd like this saved input to recognize when "Http//" is absent from the start of the variable but have no idea where to begin... is it possible to check only a portion of a string? - then have a function that will append if necessary?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

A simple solution for what you want is the following:

```
var prefix = 'http://';
if (s.substr(0, prefix.length) !== prefix)
{
    s = prefix + s;
}
```

However there are a few things you should be aware of...

The test here is case-sensitive. This means that if the string is initially `Http://example.com` this will change it to `http://Http://example.com` which is probably not what you want. You probably should also not modify any string starting with `foo://` otherwise you could end up with something like `http://https://example.com`.

On the other hand if you receive an input such as `example.com?redirect=http://othersite.com` then you probably do want to prepend `http://` so just searching for `://` might not be good enough for a general solution.

**Alternative approaches**

- Using a regular expression:

  ```
  if (!s.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+:\/\//))
  {
      s = 'http://' + s;
  }
  ```
- Using a URI parsing library such as [JS-URI](http://code.google.com/p/js-uri/).

  ```
  if (new URI(s).scheme === null)
  {
      s = 'http://' + s;
  }
  ```

**Related questions**

- [Javascript equalsIgnoreCase: case insensitive string comparation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/javascript-equalsignorecase-case-insensitive-string-comparation)
- [javascript startswith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith)
- [How do I parse a URL into hostname and path in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736513/how-do-i-parse-a-url-into-hostname-and-path-in-javascript)

Comment: Good solution. Keep it up

Comment: Note for protocol relative URLS (urls that start with) `//`, this may have unexpected results. ex: `//example.com/foo`, the code above would change it to `http:////example.com/foo`

Answer (score 127):

If you also want to allow "https://", I would use a regular expression like this:

```
if (!/^https?:\/\//i.test(url)) {
    url = 'http://' + url;
}
```

If you're not familiar with regular expressions, here's what each part means.

- `^` - Only match at the beginning of the string
- `http` - Match the literal string "http"
- `s?` - Optionally match an "s"
- `:` - Match a colon
- `\/\/` - Escape the "/" characters since they mark the beginning/end of the regular expression
- The "i" after the regular expression makes it case-insensitive so it will match "HTTP://", etc.

Comment: You should be aware that ```!/^https?:\/\//i.test(undefined)``` is ```true```.
I suggest to check if ```url``` is not falsey:
```if (!!url && !/^https?:\/\//i.test(url)) {...```

Comment: Use ```!/^(https?:)?\/\//i.test(url)``` to handle //:example.com as well.

Comment: With the regex in your answer, it's possible to write a one-liner:  'stackoverflow.com'.replace(/^(https?:\/\/)?/i, (a)=>a || 'http://')

Comment: How can we make it avoid FTP urls?

Answer (score 38):

Lifted from the [Linkenizer](http://ablazex.com/linkenizer.html) (Null won't mind)

```
link = (link.indexOf('://') === -1) ? 'http://' + link : link;
```

This will prepend `'http://'` to `link` if it can't find the `://` indicating protocol. This won't work well if `://` occurs elsewhere in the string, but it's good enough.

Examples:

```
http://www.google.com -> http://www.google.com
ftp://google.com      -> ftp://google.com
www.google.com        -> http://www.google.com
google.com            -> http://google.com
```

---

Since you said you are saving this URL, it would be a better idea to do this on the server-side, so clients who have js disabled won't mess up the links.

Comment: slight improvement: `((link.indexOf('://') === -1) && (link.indexOf('mailto:') === -1) ) ? 'http://' + link : link`

Answer (score 27):

### ES6, one liner

Here is a "modern" approach:

```
const withHttp = url => !/^https?:\/\//i.test(url) ? `http://${url}` : url;
```

You can now use `withHttp` as a function:

```
const myUrl = withHttp("www.example.org");
```

Answer (score 10):

**ES6, one liner**

```js
const withHttp = (url) => url.replace(/^(?:(.*:)?\/\/)?(.*)/i, (match, schemma, nonSchemmaUrl) => schemma ? match : `http://${nonSchemmaUrl}`);
```

Tested for (all return `http://www.google.com`):

- `www.google.com`
- `google.com`
- `//google.com`
- `http://www.google.com`
- `https://www.google.com`
- `ftp://www.google.com`

If anyone need to know how it works add a comment and I'll add an explanation.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I use for instant gratification. utilizing the keyup listener in jquery.

```
$('#url').keyup(function () {
        if (  ($(this).val().length >=5) && ($(this).val().substr(0, 5) != 'http:') && ($(this).val().substr(0, 5) != 'https') ) {
            $(this).val('http://' + $(this).val());
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks, used this, just changed the JQuery selector to ```$('input[type=url]')```

Answer (score 6):

Below code snippet checks for:

- Checks if url is not blank
- Removes stray blank spaces at start or end
- Checks for **http://example.com**, **https://example.com** AND **//example.com**

  ```
  if (!!url && !!url.trim()) { //Check if url is not blank
      url = url.trim(); //Removes blank spaces from start and end
      if (!/^(https?:)?\/\//i.test(url)) { //Checks for if url doesn't match either of: http://example.com, https://example.com AND //example.com
          url = 'http://' + url; //Prepend http:// to the URL
      }
  } else {
      //Handle empty url
  }
  ```

Comment: You shouldn't return http:// as a default, it's better to just add '//' double forward slashes.

Answer (score 5):

I altered @Mark Byers's answer to include "https://" as well.

```
function formatUrl(url){
    var httpString = 'http://'
        , httpsString = 'https://'
        ;

    if (url.substr(0, httpString.length) !== httpString && url.substr(0, httpsString.length) !== httpsString)
        url = httpString + url;

    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid regexes (and consequently another problem) by using [`new URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL):

```js
function newURL(string) {
  let url;
  try {
    url = new URL(string);

    if (!url.hostname) {
      // cases where the hostname was not identified
      // ex: user:password@www.example.com, example.com:8000
      url = new URL("https://" + string);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    url = new URL("https://" + string);
  }

  return url;
}

const url = newURL('google.com');

console.log(url); // "https://google.com/"
```

It works for any string, see the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/new-url

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (writing by memory)?

```
if (url.toUpper(url.substring(0, 7) != "HTTP://")
  url = "http://" + url;
```

Comment: `url.substring(0, 7).toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (url.indexOf('http://') != 0)
    url = 'http://' + url;
```

Answer (score 0):

I altered @Morgan Taylor's and @Mark Byer's answers to be case unsensitive. Works with http:// and https://

```
function formatUrl(url)
{
    var httpString = "http://";
    var httpsString = "https://";
    if (url.substr(0, httpString.length).toLowerCase() !== httpString && url.substr(0, httpsString.length).toLowerCase() !== httpsString)
                url = httpString + url;
    return url;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use "StartsWith" a member of System.String.

```
if (url.ToUpper().StartsWith("HTTP://"))
{ 

}
```

Comment: if (isNotC#) { return "StartWith does not exist."; }

Comment: And, I just knocked up a console app, targeting .net 3.5 and this compiles and builds fine: string url = @"http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452(v=VS.90).aspx"; if (url.ToUpper().StartsWith("HTTP://")) { Console.WriteLine("Is this c#, the method is defined in Assembly mscorlib.dll, v2.0.50727."); }

Comment: @Daniel James Bryars: It seems that "this is not C#" refers to the question, whose tags currently (rev.1) read "javascript html variables" - no C#.

Comment: Late to the game, but JavaScript now has `String.startsWith()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith