# Discover Meteor: Add http:// automatically to inputted URL

Tags: javascript, url, meteor

I've been trying to figure this on my own but ended up not being able to after many long hours.

I'm currently following the Discover Meteor Book for Meteor.js.

I noticed that submitting the post without the `http://` would link the links to `localhost:3000/submittedurl`.

I want meteor to automatically add `http://` to URLs when submitted. Logically, it wouldn't add the `http://` when a scheme is included in the input field.

```
//post_submit.js

Template.postSubmit.created = function() {
    Session.set('postSubmitErrors', {});
};

Template.postSubmit.helpers({
    errorMessage: function(field) {
        return Session.get('postSubmitErrors')[field];
    },
    errorClass: function(field) {
        return !!Session.get('postSubmitErrors')[field] ? 'has-error' : '';
    }
});

Template.postSubmit.events({
    'submit form': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var post = {
            url: $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val(),
            title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
        };

        var errors = validatePost(post);
        if (errors.title || errors.url)
            return Session.set('postSubmitErrors', errors);

        Meteor.call('postInsert', post, function(error, result) {
            // display the error to the user and abort
            if (error)
                return throwError(error.reason);

            // show this result but route anyway
            if (result.postExists)
                throwError('This link has already been posted');

            Router.go('postPage', {_id: result._id});
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: please be precise, and explain more about problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in fact this is a simple javascript question, not necessarily related to Meteor.

For example, the answer to this question [Prepending "http://" to a URL that doesn't already contain "http://"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543187/prepending-http-to-a-url-that-doesnt-already-contain-http) provides a method:

```
checkForProperURLPrefixAndFixIfNecessary = function(testUrl) {
  var prefix = 'http://';
  if (testUrl.substr(0, prefix.length) !== prefix) {
    testUrl = prefix + testUrl;
  }
  return testUrl;
}
```

or you can see other answers for different methods. I think the [JS-URI](https://code.google.com/p/js-uri/) library approach is much safer.

So let's say you have the `checkForProperURLPrefixAndFixIfNecessary(testUrl)` function declared in your source as given above, then you can change

```
var post = {
  url: $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val(),
  title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
};
```

to

```
var post = {
  url: checkForProperURLPrefixAndFixIfNecessary( $(e.target).find('[name=url]').val() ),
  title: $(e.target).find('[name=title]').val()
};
```

But once you finish through the Discover Meteor book, which is *the* greatest way of learning Meteor, take a look at the awesome https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema package or just search for *schema* or *validation* on https://atmospherejs.com/ for more robust ways of checking user input for proper type and structure.

Comment: Also, url schemes can have different contexts like http, https, ftp, scp, mailto etc, I'd rather let the user know by way of showing an error prompt instead of just going ahead and *fixing* the input assuming it is http.

Comment: Thank you so much Serkan Durusoy. I'm a designer trying to learn web development to further my knowledge and skills for web-app creations. I will try to do my best to work this out!

Comment: Discover Meteor is a great resource @SangYooKim and after completing that, make sure you read through the official http://docs.meteor.com