# How to get rid of current domain url link in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've made a simple app similiar to hacker news to understand how works with angularJS.

I have a problem, when I submit link input like:

I type **"http://www.foo.com"** is submitted and it returns as **"www.foo.com"**

otherwise, I type **"www.foo.com"** is submitted and it returns as **"localhost:3000/www.foo.com"**

I couldn't figure out how to get rid of current location of this url after of submitting a link without HTTP://

There no special conditions to manipulate this link, my app is using a lib for angularjs:

*angular-ui-router.js*

There is code

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Link test</title>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="scopeExample">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
  Your link:
    <input type="text" ng-model="url">
    <button ng-click='sayLink()'>post link</button>
  <hr>
  <a ng-href="{{link}}" target="_self">{{link}}</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.url = 'www.zombo.com';

    $scope.sayLink = function() {
      $scope.link = $scope.url;
    };
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

There an live preview
http://plnkr.co/edit/iDT0C4vi22mGMuxw8z9s?p=preview

Can anyone explain why is this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really anything to do with Angular: it's just setting the `href` attribute on the link to exactly what was typed in the input (minus any leading/trailing white space I think).

It's due to how browsers handle relative/absolute links in such tags:

- If the link starts with a protocol, like `http://`, then it treates is as a full URL
- Otherwise, if the link starts with a forward slash `/` it treats the link as being an absolute path on the current domain/protocol
- Otherwise, it treats the link as relative to the current base href (which can be the current page, or can be the same as the root path on the domain depending on what the `<base>` tag specifies)

  This is what I think is happening with `www.foo.com`. Your base href must be `http://localhost:3000/`, and so the browser treats the link as `http://localhost:3000/www.foo.com`

To sort this, you can just add the protocol if it's missing. Taking from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3543261/1319998 , you could do something like:

```
$scope.sayLink = function() {
  if (!/^https?:\/\//i.test($scope.url)) {
    $scope.link = 'http://' + url;
  }   
};
```

Comment: Wonderful, now I understand it's depending to browsers behavior, thanks for explaining!