# How can i link my (html) login page and other pages to my index page

Tags: html, css

Below is my code. I want to create a link between my `index.html` page and other page, so that whenever I click login or any other page, it should redirect me to a specific page. How can I achieve that?

I tried using `href` but it doesn't work, because I guess I have used `span` and styled that `span` in CSS. 
This is a side bar navigation responsive page.

[This is how the page looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSpeK.jpg) 
 [This is how it looks underlined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V80pk.jpg)

`index.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/d1341f9b7a.js"></script>

  <title>MyWeb</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="searchbox">
      <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="" placeholder="Type to search">
      <a class="search-btn" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
  <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
    <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
  </label>
  <div id="sidebarMenu">
    <ul class="siderbarMenuInner">
      <li> Rahul <span>MusicLibrary</span></li>
      <li> <a href="login.html"></a> <span>Login</span></li>
      <li> <a href="www.instagram.com"></a> <span>Contact Us</span></li>
      <li> <a href="about.html"></a> <span>About</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

`login.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Animated Login Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css"> 
</head> 

<body>

  <form class="box" action="index.html" method="post">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text"     name=""  placeholder="Username">
    <input type="password" name=""  placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit"  name=""  value="Login">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS code :

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden; 
  height: 100%; 
}

body{
  font-family: tahoma;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #3c6382, #82ccdd);
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.header{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: #fc466b;
  position: fixed; 
  height: 60px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}

.searchbox{
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 40px;
  right: 2%;
  background: #2f3640;
  height: 40px;
  top: 15%;
  padding: 0.1%;

}

.search-txt{
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline:none;
  float:left;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 0px; 

}

.search-btn{
  color: #fc466b;
  float:right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2f3640;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 transition: 0.4s;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.searchbox:hover > .search-txt{
  width: 500px;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.searchbox:hover > .search-btn{
  background: white;
}

.main{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.mainInner{
  display: table;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
}

#sidebarMenu{

 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 width: 250px;
 margin-top: 60px;
 transform: translateX(-250px);
 transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
 background:linear-gradient(180deg, #fc466b, #3f5efb);

}

.siderbarMenuInner{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.10);
}

.siderbarMenuInner li{
 list-style: none;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.10);
 text-decoration: none;

}
.siderbarMenuInner li span{
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:rgba(255,255,255,0.50);
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: inherit;
}

.sidebarMenuInner li a{
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;

}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #sidebarMenu{

  transform: translateX(0);
}
input[type=checkbox]{
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: none;
}

.sidebarIconToggle{

  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  top:22px;
  left: 15px;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}

.spinner{
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.horizontal{
   transition: all 0.3s;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   margin-top: 3px;
}

.diagonal.part-1{
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float:left;
}

.diagonal.part-2{
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .horizontal{
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-1{
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  margin-top: 8px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-2{
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  margin-top: -9px;
}
```

Comment: `<a href="login.html">Login</a>` try this please?

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, this will help you with the external url href issue: [href without http(s) prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803778/href-without-https-prefix)

Comment: no it does'nt work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5qas3b7y/

Comment: Thanks alot! so you removed span tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you are clicking on "Login", you only hit a span-tag instead of the link. 
Please try this instead:

```
<a href="login.html"><span>Login</span></a>
```

Comment: thanks! it worked! but now there is an underline under login and text-decoration:none doesnt help

Comment: Your downvotes on mine and others comments are not acceptable. You definitly made that mistake - and in my opinion we found the solution for you guy.

Comment: Ok, try      a { text-decoration:none;}    in your css-file.

Comment: how can i upvote your solution ? getting some 15reputation message

Comment: Its OK, don`t worry about. :-)

Comment: text decoration is not helping. i have posted img of that

Comment: May we see your whole css?

Comment: yes i added to my code you can check if there's mistake

Comment: Hm, recently created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zj0dch87/ , the underline is not shown. But i saw you added the text-decoration:none to ."siderbarMenuInner li span" instead of ".siderbarMenuInner li a" :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="sidebarMenu">
    <ul class="siderbarMenuInner">
      <li> Rahul <span>MusicLibrary</span></li>
      <li> <a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
      <li> <a href="www.instagram.com">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li> <a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Your `</a>` tag was closing before the `<span>` tag

Edit:

Add inside your css file

```
a{
text-decoration: none !important;

/* TO CHANGE BLUE COLOR*/
color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: @RahulShinde I fixed the underline for you

Comment: color: inherit made my whole letter blue with underline under it

Comment: cant i change colour for everyword except Rahul ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div id="sidebarMenu">
    <ul class="siderbarMenuInner">
      <li> Rahul <span>MusicLibrary</span></li>
      <li> <a href="login.html"><span>Login</span></a></li>
      <li> <a href="www.instagram.com"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
      <li> <a href="about.html"><span>About</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

You should enclose your `<span>` elements inside the anchor tags `<a>`.

So when you write `<a href="logn.html"></a>`, you are telling the browser to make the link clickable on an empty string. Because you haven't included any text or any other element inside the `<a>` tags!

But if you write it like this: `<a href="logn.html">LOGIN</a>`, you are telling the browser to make the link clickable when user clicks on the `LOGIN` text. Similarly you can enclose anything. You can even include an `<img>` also inside an anchor tag. Eg: `<a href="index.html"><img src="logo" /></a>`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks alot ! worked. and sorry for that downvote i did bymistakely

Comment: You can click on the `downvote` arrow button to undo it!