# how to menu item redirect to a link using href?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, href

I'm using `MenuItem` from `material-ui`, and I want to open a link in a new tab when the menu item is clicked. I'm using simple:
<`MenuItem href="www.google.com" onClick={handleClose}> Google </MenuItem>`

But nothing happens. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Material-ui's [MenuItem](https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/) does not have an `href` prop, so it will pass that down to the root element (`li` tag by default).

If you want to use an `href` you would need to use an `a` tag as the `component`, which would then pass down the `href` to it instead of an `li`. To open it in a new tab you need to also give it a prop `target="_blank"`.

Result:

```js
<MenuItem 
  href="www.google.com"
  target="_blank"
  component="a" 
  onClick={handleClose}
> Google </MenuItem>
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked, but im getting this page: http://localhost:3000/www.google.com  instead just google.com, do you know why?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43803872/9381601) for explanation of why the prefix is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can write in the `onClick={window.location.href = "www.google.com"}`

Comment: To open in a new Tab. Inside the onClick function add this: window.open(
  'www.google.com',
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);