# How to pre-convert all URLs inserted through CKEditor5 into proper URLs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, ckeditor5

With the current editor, if you add a link that doesn't contain https:// or http:// in front of the URL, it will use the link as `'https://yourownwebsite.com' + '/' + 'yourLink'` instead of taking you straight to `yourLink`.

Is there any way to set up CKEditor5 so that both www.example.com and example.com would become accepted links?

I found [an answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543187/prepending-http-to-a-url-that-doesnt-already-contain-http/3543258#3543258) to potentially parse links myself, however, I don't know how to implement it in the editor. Is there a way I could modify the editor build so as to pre-filter the URL insert with this line of code below?

The line of code below is all I'd like to implement as a pre-filter for link insertion:

```
link = (link.indexOf('://') === -1) ? 'http://' + link : link;
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm trying to solve this problem as well

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. You'd have to make your own plugin.