# Check all links protocols and add https:

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to check if all links of a page have https:// or they just start with www. and if they don't have https:// just add it to them

I'm stuck in the condition to check if they have https: or not and how to add them https:

```js
$('.rest-web a').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if(link.location.protocol !== 'https:'){
      console.log('no');
      
    } else {
      console.log('yes');
    }
  });
```

Many thanks

Comment: And what are you going to do if a link is created to email or telephone ? Adding 'https' in front of them will break their function.

Comment: There's no link to an email or phone

Comment: This needs to be done server side. Don't use JS as a crutch for a poor UI.

Answer (score -1):

Check this question:
[Prepending "http://" to a URL that doesn't already contain "http://"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543187/prepending-http-to-a-url-that-doesnt-already-contain-http)

Chose your solution for the check on the link.

In your example you can replace

`console.log('no');`

With something like:

`$(this).attr('href', 'https://' + link)`

Also keep in mind links going to non http(s) protocols, and anchor tags not having an href attribute at all.