# Check for case insensitivity in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript compare strings without being case sensitive.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919403/javascript-compare-strings-without-being-case-sensitive)

I am having two fields. I need to check whether both the fields contain the same value. If the same value then a alert is raised.

I am using validation engine jQuery.

I have a written a function like:

```
function kkkk(field, rules,i,options){
    var password=field.val();
    var username = getValueUsingElementID('username');
    if(password==username){
        return options.allrules.NotEqual.alertText;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
sss2@ and sss2@ // shows error message
sss2@ and SSS2@ // no error message is shown
```

Please can anyone help. Both the values are user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `toLowerCase()` function. That will convert your strings to all lower case characters, and the comparison will then return true whether or not there were differences in case originally:

```
if(password.toLowerCase() == username.toLowerCase()) {
   //Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert both in lover case by and than compare

```
if(password.toLowerCase() == username.toLowerCase())
{
    //sucess
}
```