# Javascript Password should not contain user's account name or parts of the user's full name that exceed two consecutive characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, passwords

I need to implement client side Password validation such that password should not contain user's account name or parts of the user's full name that exceed two consecutive characters.

I'm exposing the user name and full name on the client side. But so far I couldn't figure out the regex or any other approach to implement on the client side.

Example

```
username: test20@xyz.com
password: Usertest123 --> this should fail the validation since it contains "test" in both password and username.
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a regular expression. AFAIK, I think you'll need to solve this with good old fashioned code

Comment: The only way to do what you're asking is to pick apart the username and full name in chunks of 3 characters and do a bunch of `indexOf` checks. However, this approach is silly for a great many reasons. Are you doing this because of an explicit business requirement? If not, there are much better ways to coax password entropy out of your users.

Comment: +1 this is a legitimate question.

Comment: These are are horrible password rules to force on users.

Comment: @E.J.Brennan: I agree, though not as offensive as some others I've seen. I would be entirely happy if we abolished "password complexity requirements" completely (barring, perhaps, some high-security systems -- but ideally those would be using two- or three-factor authentication anyway).

Comment: @Tom: It would be a better question if it showed some effort to solve it first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only think of this:

```
var name = "test20@xyz", password = "usertest123"

var partsOfThreeLetters = name.match(/.{3}/g).concat(
                           name.substr(1).match(/.{3}/g),
                           name.substr(2).match(/.{3}/g) );
new RegExp(partsOfThreeLetters.join("|"), "i").test(password); // true
```

but I don't think regex is the appropriate tool here, since it would need escaping etc. You'd better use a simple `substr`/`indexOf` algorithm (see [JavaScript case insensitive string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/), [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1789945/)).

Comment: Reluctant +1 here, but only because this is a legitimate answer to the OP's question... not because I think it's a particularly good idea. In fact, now I have a headache.

Comment: Thanks, the problem for me to adopt the regex approach is to be consistent with my client side javascript validation library. I have implemented the logic in the Server side. But the error response some times take quite a long time to respond hence creating a Bad user experience. Hence for faster error response I need to take this approach. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Could you show us the serverside logic? The js should be the same one

Answer (score 1):

If you need it in TS you can type:
`
const threeParts = email.match(/.{3}/g) || [];

```
const allThreeParts = threeParts.concat(email.slice(1).match(/.{3}/g) ?? [], email.slice(2).match(/.{3}/g) ?? []);

return new RegExp(allThreeParts.join("|"), "i").test(password);
```

`