# Can a variable equal two things in an if statement?

Tags: javascript

I've tried looking around on here for this, but I'm not quite sure whether I'm phrasing it correctly.

```
if (a=="something" && a=="Something") {
//some code
}
else {
// some code
}
```

Can the a variable in this statement equal both "something" and "Something" with the capital S. I've tried just using "something" without the capital, however this doesn't work.

Comment: No and use === instead of == if it is a string. There may be a problem with incorrect string parsing.

Comment: `a` can't be equal to both "something" and "Something", which is what you are testing for, that if condition will always be false. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The variable itself cant equal both "something" and "Something". But, it can equal "something" OR "Something" `if (a=="something" || a=="Something")`

Comment: in its most basic form http://jsfiddle.net/Rd5Ly/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but just use `toLowerCase`:

```
if (a.toLowerCase() === 'something') {
    // something here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Does the amount of "=" in the statement make a difference because your code only works how I want it to when only two "=" are used. Anyway, I feel yours is the best answer as it works with all variations on something. E.g. SoMething, with the capitalized m.

Comment: `===` makes sure that the type is the same as well (so both `a` and `'something'` are strings). `==` doesn't check type.

Answer (score 2):

This will never work, as `a` can **never** hold 2 Strings at the same time.

What you are eventually looking for is `||`

```
if (a=="something" || a=="Something") {
//some code
}
else {
  // some code
}
```

a logical OR, which means that `a` can either be  `"something"` **OR** `"Something"`

What you are doing right now is checking if `a` is `"something"` **AND** `"Something"` at the same time *(which is not possible)*

Comment: thanks. the `||` will definitely come in useful in the future and your explanation was very helpful. I didn't rate yours as best answer as it doesn't cover all variations on something (which letters are uppercase) and I imagine I would have to do it manually. It's my fault for not explaining this in my question. However, when I'm able to I'll rate your answer up.

Comment: You're welcome =)
I'm glad enough that this will help you in the future.

Thanks, I appreciate that =) , though you don't have to bother coming back here =) I'm here, more for the sake of learning and helping others out than for rep, anyway.

I wish you the best for your future as a programmer, keep learning =)

Answer (score 1):

Not at the same time. You probably want an OR.

```
  if(a === "something" || a === "Something"){
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is check your variable ignoring case like this :

```
a.toUpperCase() === "SOMETHING";
```

Note this will work with "SoMeThinG" as well (and every combination of case, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/javascript-equalsignorecase-case-insensitive-string-comparation) for more about case insensitive comparison)
And as other answers says : You are probably looking for `||` operator.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just do `a.toUpperCase() === 'SOMETHING'`?

Comment: Thank you for answering, but what's the difference between `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: @LiamB `toUpperCase` turns the string all `"UPPERCASE"` and `toLowerCase` turns it all `"lowercase"`