# Is there a way to add different answers to this validation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, spam-prevention

I have a simple spam trap that asks users to type the color of something, currently the validation code is:

```
      if (theForm.color.value != "blue")
  {
    alert("Please Type The Color");
    theForm.color.focus();
    return (false);
  }
```

Unfortunately, this will return false if a user uses caps like Blue or BLUE. Is there a simple way to add acceptable values such as;

```
 if (theForm.color.value != "blue" "Blue")
```

or

```
 if (theForm.color.value != "blue, Blue, BLUE")
```

Side Note: I'm unfamiliar with this language, what books would you suggest to get me started?

Comment: [JavaScript case insensitive string comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/javascript-case-insensitive-string-comparison). You can use `.toLowerCase()` similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can simply convert it to lower case first and then check it. This way, you just need to add one condition and do the coding. JavaScript will convert the upper case letters to the lower case and then check the condition.

```
if (theForm.color.value.toLowerCase() != "blue") {
   // now compare it, it was hard to understand which language
   // you're using, JavaScript or C#
}
```

..other wise to add more cases you do this (**More conditions**)

```
if (theForm.color.value != "blue" && theForm.color.value != "Blue" && 
    theForm.color.value != "BLUE") {
    // code here..
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

`.toLowerCase()` works on strings only.

*Which language are you using by the way? Tell me, so that I can edit the answer if needed.*

Comment: I think it is Javascript on a .asp site.

Comment: You _think_ it is? :-/

Comment: here is the start of the code on the .asp page:  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">