# How to compare the order of two sets of data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got two sets of data:

```
var array = ["one" , "two" , "three" , "Four" , "Five"];

var T1 = "One" ;
var T2 = "two" ;
var T3 = "three" ;
var T4 = "Four" ;
var T5 = "Five" ;
```

I want to check the order of data in both sets, I was trying this way:

```
if(T1==array[0] && T2==array[1] && T3 ==array[2] && T4==array[3] && T5==array[4])
{
    alert('Yes');
}

else
{
    alert('No');
}
```

But i'm getting alert as **"No"**.

Could you please let me know how to resolve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/85utz097/

Comment: `"One"` and `"one"` are not the same string. See http://jsfiddle.net/85utz097/2/ Did you want the comparison to be case-insensitive? If that's the case, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/javascript-case-insensitive-string-comparison for example.

Comment: Try `T1.toUpperCase()==array[0].toUpperCase()` if you don't need to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is case-sensitive, therefore "One" is not the same as "one" in your array.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting "No" because

```
One != one
```

Change this:

```
var T1 = "one" ;
```

and you will get a "YES"!!

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/85utz097/1/)

Answer (score 0):

== is case sensitive and your T1 is "One" and should be "one"

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `T1.toUpperCase()==array[0].toUpperCase() or T1.toLowerCase()==array[0].toLowerCase()`

see [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/85utz097/4/)