# Compare strings without being case-sensitive

Tags: javascript, web, compare, case-sensitive

I have problem with a variable I made (it's a string) in JavaScript. It will be `prompt` from the user and then with the `switch` I will check if it is true or not. Then when I input it upper case it will say it is identified as a another var.

Here is my code:

```js
var grade = prompt("Please enter your class") ;

switch ( grade ){
    
    case "firstclass" :
         alert("It's 500 $")
         break;
    case "economic" :
         alert("It's 250 $")
         break;
    default:
         alert("Sorry we dont have it right now");

}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2140627/830125. Those who have posted or might post answers: please do not answer questions that are blatant duplicates, despite the easy rep gain. Flag as a duplicate instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @nicael stated just lowercase what they input. However, if you need to preserve the way it was input and only compare using the lowercase equivalent, use this:

```
var grade = prompt("Please enter your class") ;

switch ( grade.toLowerCase() ){

  case "firstclass" :
     alert("It's $500");
     break;
  case "economic" :
     alert("It's $250");
     break;
  default :
     alert("Sorry we don't have it right now");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just lower case it initially.

```
var grade = prompt("Please enter your class").toLowerCase() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the entire string to lower case by using the String prototype method `toLowerCase()` and compare the two that way.

To keep the input the same, mutate the string during your switch statement:

```
switch( grade.toLowerCase() ) {
  // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always compare uppercase string with uppercase values in case sensitive languages.
Or lower with lower.

```
var grade = prompt("Please enter your class") ;

switch (grade.toUpperCase())
{    
case "FIRSTCLASS" :
     alert("It's 500 $")
     break;
case "ECONOMIC" :
     alert("It's 250 $")
     break        ;
default   :
     alert("Sorry we dont have it right now");
}
```