# Switch statement not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I have this block of switch statements, which the control variable has type string. I compared the value of this variable with another string in an if statement, it works. But it doesn't work if I put it in a switch statement.

The code is below:

```
type = $('serType');
    if (type == "Age"){
        logger.info('Age'.toLowerCase());
    }
    switch (type){
        case "TV":
            columnHeader = "";
            break;
        case 'Age':
        logger.info("i am in age case");
            columnHeader = "'id', 'pat_name', 'pat_age' ";
            break;              
        default:
        logger.info("i am in default case");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: what you mean by ``$('serType')`` ???

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `toLowerCase()` in your `case` statement, converting `"Age"` to `"age"`:

```
case 'Age'.toLowerCase()
```

Whereas in your `if` statement you are not doing this:

```
if (type == "Age")
```

`"Age"` and `"age"` are not the same thing. To fix this, remove the `.toLowerCase()` from your `case` statement:

```
case 'Age'
```

---

If you want to be able to catch both `"Age"` *and* `"age"`, see this question: [JavaScript case insensitive string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/javascript-case-insensitive-string-comparison).

Comment: Sorry I that toLowerCase function is a mistake. It doesn't work even I remove the function. I wanted to test whether it works with lower case or not. Could you try to find the problem in my code again?

Comment: @TrungBún are you getting any JavaScript errors? Is `logger` defined?

Comment: It's all defined. I tried to print every single variable and they aren't null or empty. As you can see from the code above, the if statement works, but the switch statement doesn't ..

Comment: @TrungBún there must be a different problem. Your JavaScript code works as is: http://jsfiddle.net/8tuLcq5q/

Comment: Is there any way that I can check type of variable in JavaScript? After auto wraping? Maybe the variable type is char or any other datatype. Sorry my JavaScript skill is weak..

Comment: @TrungBún char doesn't exist in JavaScript. You can use `typeof` to check its type: `if (typeof "Age" == "string")`.