# How do I make a case in-sensitive text input?

Tags: javascript, case, case-insensitive

My friend is working on a fun Javascript web application where you type something in the text box, and the computer returns you a result, but it is case-sensitive. Can he make it case-insensitive? We have tried to use:

```
var areEqual = string1.toUpperCase() === string2.toUpperCase();
```

which was on [JavaScript case insensitive string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/javascript-case-insensitive-string-comparison), but he cannot figure out how to use that.

```
function isValid() {
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    if (password == "Shut Up")
        { alert('HOW ABOUT YOU!') }

    else if (password == "No")
        { alert('You just did') }

}
```

Comment: This post is not suitable for redaction as there is no PII involved (phone/email/IP addresses). You can request that this question be disassociated from your account instead. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/584192)?

Answer (score 1):

Please, if you're going to do this, use `switch`! The only real difference between `toLowerCase` as opposed to `toUpperCase` here is that the values in the case lines won't be shouting at you.

```
function isValid() {
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    switch (password.toLowerCase()){
        case "shut up":
            alert('HOW ABOUT YOU!');
        break;
        case "no":
            alert('You just did');
        break;
        case "okay":
            alert('Okay');
        break;

        // ...

        case "something else":
            alert('Really?');
        break;
        default:
            alert('Type Something Else')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `.toUpperCase()` behind your variables:

```
else if (password == "No")
  {alert('You just did')}
```

becomes:

```
else if (password.toUpperCase() == "No".toUpperCase())
  {alert('You just did')}
```

or just:

```
else if (password.toUpperCase() == "NO") //Notice that "NO" is upper case.
  {alert('You just did')}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that this way, for example in the first else-if block:

```
 else if (password.toUpperCase() == "No".toUpperCase())
 {alert('You just did')}
```

The function toUpperCase, applied to a string, returns it's uppercased version, so for No it would be NO. If the password variable holds any lower-upper case combo of the word no, such as "No", "nO", "NO" or "no", then password.toUpperCase() will be "NO".
The previous code is equivalent to

```
 else if (password.toUpperCase() == "NO")
 {alert('You just did')}
```