# Case sensitivity of argument?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to pass case sensitivity together with an argument?

```
   var user = {
  'name' : 'Jim',
  'lastName' : 'Xydas',
  'fullName' : function(){
    return this.name + " " + this.lastName
  },

  'address' : {
    'country' : "Greece",
    'town'    : "Thessaloniki",
    'street'  : "il.ap 15",

    "isFromTown" : function(n){
        return this.town == n ? true : false;
    }
  }
};

var checkUser = user.address.isFromTown("thessaloniki");

console.log(checkUser);
```

What I'm trying to do here is pass the argument as "thessaloniki" and print true, ignoring the first (or more) uppercase letter(s).

https://jsfiddle.net/DimitriXd4/mfpat7so/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this.town.toLowerCase();`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/javascript-case-insensitive-string-comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`String#toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) or [`String#toLocaleLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) for both strings for comparing.

```js
var user = {
    'name' : 'Jim',
    'lastName' : 'Xydas',
    'fullName' : function() {
        return this.name + " " + this.lastName
     },
    'adress' : {
        'country' : "Greece",
        'town'    : "Thessaloniki",
        'street'  : "il.ap 15",
        "isFromTown" : function(n){
            return this.town.toLocaleLowerCase() == n.toLocaleLowerCase();
        }
    }
};

var checkUser = user.adress.isFromTown("thessaloniki");

console.log(checkUser);
```

Comment: Thank you that works lovely and easily :).

Comment: if you use some spacial characters, you may have a look to `String#toLocaleLowerCase`

Comment: @DimitrisXydas - if you're using the greek alphabet, rather than straight [a-zA-Z] characters, Nina's comment is important!

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just pass another parameter

```
"isFromTown" : function(n, caseSensitive){
    return caseSensitive 
      ? this.town == n 
      : this.town.toLowerCase() == n.toLowerCase();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mfpat7so/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use the below snippet in the function

```js
return (this.town.toUpperCase()) === (n.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: @Jamiec edited it. Thanks!

Comment: @Jamiec `()` reduntant also