# search in Angular 2 with First Name, Last Name and Email

Tags: angular, typescript

## Detail

I am trying to implement search pipe through which user can search with email/ firstname/ lastname but right now it iss perfectly fine with email single search item. I want to search same text enter in input with email first name and last name.

## Image

[image]

## Search Pipe

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
    name: "search"
})

export class SearchPipe {

    transform(value, term) {
        console.log(term + ' ' + value);
        if (term == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return value.filter((item) => item.Email.includes(term));
    }
}
```

### Response

```
{
    "Id":1,
    "ApimId":"1",
    "FirstName":"Super",
    "LastName":"Admin","
    "Email":"ahmed@gmail.com"   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done the hardest part, just change your pipe to filter based on **email** or **first name** or **last name**

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
    name: "search"
})

export class SearchPipe {

    transform(value, term) {
        console.log(term + ' ' + value);
        if (term == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return value.filter((item) => {
            return item.Email.includes(term) || item.FirstName.includes(term) || item.LastName.includes(term);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It solves my problem just one thing more, search is case sensative how I can resolve this?

Comment: @MalikKashmiri a simple way would be to uppercase your strings, but check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/javascript-case-insensitive-string-comparison