# case insensitive textContent in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, html, case-sensitive

I have the following code that uses me to do stuff with all links with a certain textContent in a webpage:

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a b');
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        let link = links[i];
        if (link.textContent == 'remove') {
        link.click();
        }
    }
```

In a certain webpage the links where named 'remove' on the webpage but appeared as 'Remove' (not the capitalized R) in DOM.

At the start I didn't know it is the case with the DOM and didn't understand why the code didn't work.

Gladly, I had the feeling it is in different in the DOM and indeed I saw I was right and when I changed it in the code from `if (link.textContent == 'remove')` to `if (link.textContent == 'Remove')`, the code worked.

---

As a beginner I ask only out of curiosity (because I'm humbly aware that such webpage-DOM discrepancies can occur):

Is there a way to make the textContent check to be case insensitive in vanilla JS?

I believe the answer would include regex but I've to take any regex course (should happen soon) and at the moment, cannot answer it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use **toLowerCase** function?

```
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a b');
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    let link = links[i];
    if (link.textContent.toLowerCase() == 'remove') {
    link.click();
    }
}
```

It wouldn't matter if it compares **remove**, **Remove** or even **REMOVE**.

Answer (score 1):

I would send you to this page:
[JavaScript case insensitive string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/javascript-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

In brief, you can simply compare the upper (or lower versions) of two strings to check if they are ignoreCaseEqual, by using **toUpperCase()** or **toLowerCase()** function as explained below:

```
string1.toUpperCase() === string2.toUpperCase();
string1.toLowerCase() === string2.toLowerCase();
```

In your case just use:

```
if (link.textContent.toLowerCase() == 'remove') { 
    // since remove is already lowercase
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javscript function to change the text to lowercase.
in this i just create a variable name text and then use toLowerCase() function in if condition. Thanks

```
 var text = link.textContent;
 if (text.toLowerCase() == 'remove') {
     text.click();
 }
```

EDIT: code indented