# "Idiot Check" in JavaScript (.toLowerCase and .toUpperCase)

Tags: javascript

In my code, "SiAff" won't be the correct answer...
I want to use ".toLowerCase" and ".toUpperCase", but I don't know how to do that.
Any help would be appreciate

```
var Que = prompt("What's my name")

if (Que == "Siaff") {
    document.write("Correct!")
}

else {
    document.write("Wrong!")
}
```

Comment: `Que.toLowerCase() == 'siaff'`…?!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Show effort - for example google mdn toLowerCase to read how to use toLowerCase - or this: https://www.google.nl/search?q=how+to+compare+strings+case+insensitive+javascript which [returns the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/javascript-case-insensitive-string-comparison) as one of the first

Comment: Looking at the description and code OP only wants capitalized name to be correct.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this [`Que.toLowerCase()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjmh6jlvIvWAhXEPRoKHdrbAqIQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2FJSREF%2Fjsref_tolowercase.asp&usg=AFQjCNEZrTbl7c1etzdjSZ4TmJeyq_RlBg)

```js
var Que = prompt("What's my name")

if (Que.toLowerCase() === "siaff") {
    document.write("Correct!")
}

else {
    document.write("Wrong!")
}
```

Comment: `===`, not `==`

Comment: @Cerbrus: It makes exactly zero difference above.

Comment: Still a good habit.

Comment: And flagged by TypeScript

Comment: @mplungjan: `==`, you mean?

Comment: Also, although not really an issue here. `exactly zero difference` is not strictly true, if performance was an issue.  As == has a few extra equality checks to do.  But yeah, I'm been pedantic here. :)

Comment: Well, OP doesn't care.. even the `In my code, "SiAff" won't be the correct answer...` went out the window