# Angular 2/4 String Comparison with Ignore Case

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm comparing a number of fields in an `Angular 2` template and it works for `same case` properties but returns `false` for the same string on different cases. Is there a way to make it `case insensitive` perhaps through a simple `pipe`?

```
<div *ngIf="query?.firstName == address.foreName"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript case insensitive string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/javascript-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use  **`===`** with **`toLowercase()`**

```
<div *ngIf="query?.firstName.toLowerCase() === address.foreName.toLowerCase()"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use Angular pipe.

```
<div *ngIf="(query?.firstName | lowercase) === (address.foreName | lowercase)"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing lot of string operations in your application, I suggest using a third party library like [this](https://github.com/jprichardson/string.js) one -

**How to install**

```
npm install --save string
```

**Import**

```
var S = require('string');
```

**Ignorecase Compare String**

```
var isEqual = S('ignoreCase').equalsIgnoreCase('IGNORECASE')
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert Both string into lowercase and then compare.
Find the below code.

```
 comapre(){
    let str1 = "Welcome to Xyx World";
    let str2 = "world";
    if(str1.toLowerCase().includes(str2.toLowerCase())){
      console.log("Found");
    }else{
      console.log("Not Found");
    }
  }
```