# Comparing 2 email addresses in 2 fields with javascript

Tags: javascript

My requirement is - To compare if 2 email address are different (comparing case as well. if different then to proceed. if same, then to get an error.

tom.smith@gmail.com  & Tom.Smith@gmail.com = Same - error should be received.

I am trying to achieve this through javascript. When I match the email addresses as equal even the case (upper/lower) is being considered. But if am trying to check on not equal, the code is not checking the case and no error is appearing.

Code -

```
if ((context.Email1.value) !== (context.Email2.value)) { 
    return true; 
} else { 
    return false; 
}
```

Please advice.

Regards,
PS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript case insensitive string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/javascript-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Comment: Need more information with respect to code. what is those context? You can however try `context.Email1.toLowerCase().value !== context.Email2.toLowerCase().value`

Comment: `"tom.smith@gmail.com" == "Tom.Smith@gmail.com"` returns `false`. Or do you want it to return `true`? And don't do `if(cond){return true} else {return false}`, just `return (cond)`

Comment: tom.smith@gmail.com" == "Tom.Smith@gmail.com should return false

Comment: [but it does](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLGBPP?editors=0010)

Comment: "tom.smith@gmail.com" != "Tom.Smith@gmail.com" should return false. if this helps

Comment: then they just have to be equals. you can `.toLowerCase()` these strings in order them to be equals

Comment: where should i add the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return context.Email1.value.toLowerCase() === context.Email2.value.toLowerCase();
```