# in Javascript, I want the code to return only the name that has the same ID on different line in HTML

Tags: javascript

```
let users = [
            {id: "Ca", name: "John"},
            {id: "Ca", name: "Pete"},
            {id: "Ca", name: "Zed"},
            {id: "Cb", name: "Xed"},
            {id: "Cb", name: "Cas"},
            {id: "Cb", name: "Fre"},
            {id: "Cc", name: "Pete"},
            {id: "Cc", name: "Mary"}
        ];

        let user = users.filter(item => {
                    return item.id === 'ca';
        })

        console.log(user.id);
```

i want the code display on html web page to be

if id = 'ca'

 John

Pete

Zed

and if ID='Cb'

Xed

Cas

Fre

Comment: where in the page should it be displayed? is there some specific DIV that should contain the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mistake in your approach.

.filter returns an array. so, you should loop over user (returned value) to print user.id. And '===' is case sensitive, if u check for 'ca', as per your data, there will be no return. Use 'Ca' to check return data

Example:

```js
let users = [
            {id: "Ca", name: "John"},
            {id: "Ca", name: "Pete"},
            {id: "Ca", name: "Zed"},
            {id: "Cb", name: "Xed"},
            {id: "Cb", name: "Cas"},
            {id: "Cb", name: "Fre"},
            {id: "Cc", name: "Pete"},
            {id: "Cc", name: "Mary"}
        ];

let user = users.filter(item => {
            return item.id === 'Ca';
    })

user.forEach(el => document.write(el.name, '<br>'));
```

Comment: I've copied your pen to the answer - the SO snippets work very similar to fiddle/pen but keep the code in one place (in SO).  Also fixed your typo in the last line, hope that's ok.

Comment: Thanks Boss. It Worked

Answer (score 0):

```js
let users = [
        {id: "Ca", name: "John"},
        {id: "Ca", name: "Pete"},
        {id: "Ca", name: "Zed"},
        {id: "Cb", name: "Xed"},
        {id: "Cb", name: "Cas"},
        {id: "Cb", name: "Fre"},
        {id: "Cc", name: "Pete"},
        {id: "Cc", name: "Mary"}
    ];
const output = document.querySelector('#output');
    users.filter(item => item.id === "Ca").forEach(item => {
    output.innerHTML += '<p>'+item.name+'</p>';
    })
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
let userNames = users.filter(item => {
                return item.id === 'Ca';
    }).map(item => item.name);
```

You now have an array of names that you can output as desired, updated snippet:

```js
let users = [
            {id: "Ca", name: "John"},
            {id: "Ca", name: "Pete"},
            {id: "Ca", name: "Zed"},
            {id: "Cb", name: "Xed"},
            {id: "Cb", name: "Cas"},
            {id: "Cb", name: "Fre"},
            {id: "Cc", name: "Pete"},
            {id: "Cc", name: "Mary"}
        ];
        
var names = users.filter(item => {
      return item.id === 'Ca';
    })
    .map(x => x.name);
    
console.log(names)  
// or join / loop to get on separate lines, this outputs as an array in the console
```

Note that `ca !== Ca` so changed in the code above for simplicity.  If you want case-insensitive comparison there are various methods [described in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/how-to-do-case-insensitive-string-comparison)