# Javascript recognize sentence regardless of upper and lower case anywhere in the sentence

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
    bot.on('message', message => {

        if (message.content === 'This is a test') {
           message.channel.send("Hello!");

        }
});
```

So I want the bot to recognize the sentence even if it is spelled something like this: "THIs iS A tEsT"

Comment: Just compare either lower or uppercases of both. To detect it anywhere in the sentence use `indexOf`. `message.content.toLowerCase().indexOf('this is a test') !== -1`

Comment: That really helped me! Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do case insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/how-to-do-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('this is a test')) {
           message.channel.send("Hello!");
        }
```