# Removing value from array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Im new to software development and have been taking a class, im having an issue with finding out how to remove items in an array based on a 2nd argument character

Write a function "removeWordsWithChar" that takes 2 arguments:

1. an array of strings
2. a string of length 1 (ie: a single character)
   It should return a new array that has all of the items in the first argument except those that contain a character in the second argument (case-insensitive).

Examples:

----removeWordsWithChar(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], 'b') --> ['aaa', 'ccc']

----removeWordsWithChar(['pizza', 'beer', 'cheese'], 'E') --> ['pizza']

```
function removeWordsWithChar(arrString, stringLength) {
  const arr2 = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < arrString.length; i++) {
   const thisWord = arrString[i];
    if (thisWord.indexOf(stringLength) === -1) {
     arr2.push(thisWord);
    }
  }
return arr2;
}
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)  `arr2.filter(x=>!x.toLowerCase().includes(strLength.toLowerCase()))`

Comment: it should be  case insensitive, so use `if (thisWord.toLowerCase().indexOf(stringLength.toLowerCase())  === -1)`

Comment: that worked! i cant believe i missed the lowercase. Thank you!

Comment: you can also use localeCompare https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do case insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/how-to-do-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Answer (score 1):

As they said in comments you can use filter like this:

```js
function removeWordsWithChar(elems, string){
  return elems.filter(elem => !elem.toLowerCase().includes(string.toLowerCase()));
}
```