# make word recoginized even if it on mix between upper case and lower case

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so im making a bot that will delete any blacklisted words. but the problem is , the bot wont regonize the word if the word contain upper case. For example hi. if i typed hi the bot will delete the text. but if i typed Hi or hI the bot wont regonize the word

```js
bot.on("message", (message) => {
    const swearword =["hi"]
    if( swearword.some(word => message.content.includes(word)) ) {
        message.delete();
        message.reply("That word is blacklisted").then(m => m.delete({timeout: 6000}));
        console.log(message.author + (" said the blacklisted word"))
      }});
```

Comment: Turn the incoming message to lowercase with: `message.content.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to use `toLowerCase()`?

```
bot.on("message", (message) => {
    const swearword =["hi"]
    if( swearword.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word)) ) {
        message.delete();
        message.reply("That word is blacklisted").then(m => m.delete({timeout: 6000}));
        console.log(message.author + (" said the blacklisted word"))
      }});
```

Comment: This is of course a [huge dupe](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+case+insensitive+compare+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) or lower/uppercase the word before checking.

```js
let swearWord = "damned";
let inputString = "I'll be dAmnEd";

// lowercase the word before check
console.log(inputString.toLowerCase().includes(swearWord));

// regular expression
console.log(/\bdamned\b/i.test(swearWord));
// or
console.log( RegExp(`\\b${swearWord}\\b`, `i`).test(swearWord));
```

Comment: [Huge dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/how-to-do-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that, if you are comparing / checking for words from a `swearWords` collection, you should convert both the words in the same format.

I would suggest looking into `toLowerCase()` functionality to convert both the comparision operators `toLowerCase()`.

You may update your code as below:

```
bot.on("message", (message) => {
    const swearword =["hi"]
    
    // storing the incoming message content in lowercase in another variable.
    const incomingMessage = message.content.toLowerCase()

    if( swearword.some(word => incomingMessage.includes( word.toLowerCase() )) ) {
        message.delete();
        message.reply("That word is blacklisted").then(m => m.delete({timeout: 6000}));
        console.log(message.author + (" said the blacklisted word"))
      }});
```

Comment: Converting only the `incoming message content` to lower case might work only if you have all the words in your `swearWords array` in lowercase. But it would be a good practice to  compare words in the same `case`