# Is there any way to treat lowercase characters the same as uppercase characters in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The reason I ask this is because I have a discord bot that responds to commands, but it only works if it is lowercase, so the command "hey bot" returns hello @user but "hey BOT" doesn't work.

Comment: Just use javascript's native toLowerCase method... `"SoMe StRiNg".toLowerCase();` returns `"some string"`... The `/` should be returned as `/`, so there shouldn't be a problem with that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do case insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/how-to-do-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, you can do `string.toLowerCase();` function, to convert a string to lower case. For example, in the code below, if you say "hey bot" it works, but if you say "HEY BOT", it will not respond:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content == "hey bot" {
        message.reply("Hey user!");
    }
});
```

If we want it to ignore case, do the following:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content.toLowerCase() == "hey bot" {
        message.reply("Hey user!");
    }
});
```

Now that will work whether we type "hey bot", "hey BoT" or "HEY BOT".