# MongoDB and NextJS: Find a certain data matches regardless if uppercase or lowercase

Tags: mongodb, next.js

The goal of this code is to display the current numbers of death, recoveries and critical for covid 19 around the world.

The search function codes are as follows:

```
const search = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault() //to avoid page redirection
        const countryMatch = countryCollection.find(country => country.country_name === targetCountry)
        if (!countryMatch || countryMatch === null|| countryMatch === 'undefined') {
            alert("Country Does Not Exist, use another name.")
            setName("")
            setTargetCountry("")
        } else {
            setName(countryMatch.country_name)
            
            setDeathCount(toNum(countryMatch.deaths))
            setCriticalCount(toNum(countryMatch.serious_critical))
            setRecoveryCount(toNum(countryMatch.total_recovered))
        }
    }
```

Our task is to find a country regardless if its in upper or lower case. Eg: Malaysia vs malaysia.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do case insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/how-to-do-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**REGULAR EXPRESSION**

What you need is regular expression or RegExp.  MongoDb supports regular expression for your searches.

In Your case it can be something like

```
countryCollections.find({'country':new RegExp(countryName,flag)},callback)
```

flag determines how you want to search
for case insensitive search use 'i'

More about RegExp can be found on mongoDB docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Answer (score 0):

According to your usage of MongoDB, I would say, that this case is an excellent case to using [text indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/).

Here is an example for you:

```
Schema.index( 
  // making field available for $text search and $meta sorting
  {
    'field': 'text', 
    'embedDoc.field': 'text',
  },
  {
    //options of index
    weights: // weight for each field
      {
        'field': 2,
        'embedDoc.field': 1,
      },
    name: 'Countries', // Index Name for Mongo Compass and .explain debug
  })
```

I guess you should try that. It will solve all your potential problems with text search. Like `'` or diacritic symbols in searching, lower-uppercase and so on. But please, check the documentation of text indexes, before implementing them, it's quite sensitive and flexible for any cases. But there is no universal silver bullet.