# Count the same words regardless of the case sensitivity, or padding

Tags: javascript, typescript

for example:
`"themselves"`, `"Themselves"` or `" THEMSelveS "` (note the leading and trailing spaces), should be
counted as `themselves: 3`

My code:

```
const { readFile, readFileSync } = require('fs');


let file = 'C:\Users\eeroj\source\repos\Nodejs\pish\pish';


function countRepeatedWords(sentence) {
let words = sentence.split(" ");
let wordMap = {};

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    let currentWordCount = wordMap[words[i]];
    let count = currentWordCount ? currentWordCount : 0;
    wordMap[words[i]] = count + 1;
}

const sortedEntries = Object.entries(wordMap).sort(([a,], [b,]) => a.localeCompare(b));
const sortedWordMap = Object.fromEntries(sortedEntries);


return sortedWordMap
return wordMap;

}

words = readFileSync(file).toString();
console.log(countRepeatedWords(words));
```

Comment: Convert every word to lower case with `toLowerCase()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do case insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/how-to-do-case-insensitive-string-comparison)

Comment: People are so fast with their answers :D yeah, toLowerCase should let you handle each word as lowercase regardless of how many letters are uppercase when being read.

Comment: @eerojyrgenson you should read the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/how-to-do-case-insensitive-string-comparison), there are more robust solutions available with more explanation than what has been provided here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) function:

```
let words = sentence.split(" ");
let wordMap = {};

for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    const key = words[i].toLowerCase();
    let currentWordCount = wordMap[key];
    let count = currentWordCount ? currentWordCount : 0;
    wordMap[key] = count + 1;
}
```

I would also suggest you to use [`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop, [remove empty cells](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), define everything as `const` and use [Nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```
const words = sentence.split(" ").filter(word => word); // returns if word isn't empty
const wordMap = {};

for (let word of words) {
    const key = word.toLowerCase();
    const currentWordCount = wordMap[key];
    wordMap[key] = (currentWordCount ?? 0) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert every word to lower case with [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) and [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) spaces.

```
for (let word of words) {
    word = word.trim().toLowerCase();
    wordMap[word] = (wordMap[word] ?? 0) + 1;
}
```

Notes:

- Instead of using `.trim()` you could also just split my one or more spaces: `let words = sentence.split(/ +/)`.
- You might want to use a `Map` instead of an object or at least use `Object.create(null)` to not mix your data with built in properties.