# If statement error when it changed to case sensitive

Tags: javascript, if-statement, case-sensitive

I created code to check a particular value in the input search box. If it is, the web will focus on the searched element.

My html

```
<input type="search" id="search-box" placeholder="Search">
<button type="submit" id="searchbar" onclick="Focus()"</button>Search</button>
```

My JavaScript

```
function Focus(){
    var search = document.getElementById("search-box").value;
    

    if(search == "about"){
            document.getElementById("about").focus();
        }
        else{
            alert("Not Found");
        }
}
```

This is working, but if I change to this
`if(search == "about" || “About”)`
Then the **else statement** is not working.

Is there any other method to make **about** case sensitive
Like *About, AbOut, aBoUT, etc* all are equal

Comment: Because that’s the wrong syntax. It should be `if(search == "about" || search == "About")` (also you’re using smart quotes). A better way is to convert `search` to lowercase first before comparison so you don’t need to compare it against all combinations of upper and lowercases.

Comment: I can't comment, so... if you mean case insensitive...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140627/how-to-do-case-insensitive-string-comparison

Answer (score 0):

You could use `search.toLowerCase() == "about"` to see if it is a case insensitive match. Make sure you're using the right quotation marks. As you've used curly quotes in some instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do:

```
const toCompare = 'AboUT';

if(toCompare.toLowerCase() === 'about'){
 // --
}else{
 // --
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the if statement as below.

```
if (search == "about" || search == "About"){}
```

But as you mentioned, there can be many combinations of capitals and simples. So you should convert all the text to simple (convert to a standard format) and do the check like below.

```
if (search.toLowerCase() == "about"){}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(search == "about" || “About”)` will always evaluate true as "About" is a non empty string and is Truthy.
You need to write `if(search == "about" || search == “About”)`

Alternatively, a better syntax is to not make it case-sensitive, and write

```
if(search.toLowerCase() == "about")
```