# Could I simplify the following javascript logical OR code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, simplify

I have a code in my project but it is kind of clunky. Could anyone help me to simplify the following code?

`if (a == "good" || a == "beautiful || a == "pretty"|| a == "excellent" || a == "superb"|| a == "spectacular")`

Could I make this into some sort of array and then use that array in this if code?

Comment: It looks fine to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could use a Hash-Set structure instead: in JS this is `Set` (or `Set<T>` in TypeScript):

```
const positiveWords = new Set( [ "good", "beautiful", "pretty", "excellent", "superb", "spectacular" ] );
```

Usage:

```
if( positiveWords.has( a ) ) {
    
}
```

Note that you'll need to convert `a` to lowercase first. If you want case-insensitive (or accent-insensitive, or other culture/locale-specific comparison rules) [then use `Intl` and/or `localeCompare`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2140723/159145).

Answer (score 2):

```
if (["good", "beautiful", "pretty", "excellent", "superb", "spectacular"].includes(a)) {...}
```